# Android: Expand/collapse animation

Tags: android, animation

Let's say I have a vertical linearLayout with :

```
[v1]
[v2]
```

By default v1 has visibily = GONE. I would like to show v1 with an expand animation and push down v2 at the same time.

I tried something like this:

```
Animation a = new Animation()
{
    int initialHeight;

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        final int newHeight = (int)(initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
        v.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
        v.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
        initialHeight = height;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
};
```

But with this solution, I have a blink when the animation starts. I think it's caused by v1 displaying full size before the animation is applied.

With javascript, this is one line of jQuery! Any simple way to do this with android?

Answer (score 797, accepted):

I see that this question became popular so I post my actual solution. The main advantage is that you don't have to know the expanded height to apply the animation and once the view is expanded, it adapts height if content changes. It works great for me.

```
public static void expand(final View v) {
    int matchParentMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(((View) v.getParent()).getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    int wrapContentMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    v.measure(matchParentMeasureSpec, wrapContentMeasureSpec);
    final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
    
    // Older versions of android (pre API 21) cancel animations for views with a height of 0.
    v.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    : (int)(targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };
    
    // Expansion speed of 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration((int)(targetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    v.startAnimation(a);
}

public static void collapse(final View v) {
    final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            if(interpolatedTime == 1){
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int)(initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };
    
    // Collapse speed of 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration((int)(initialHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

As mentioned by @Jefferson in the comments, you can obtain a smoother animation by changing the duration (and hence the speed) of the animation. Currently, it has been set at a speed of 1dp/ms

Comment: v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));     In some cases(my - ListView) this mismatch leads to wrong targtetHeight value

Comment: @Tom Esterez  This does work,but not very smoothly. Is there any additional work to make it smoothly?

Comment: @acntwww This is due to displaying all the child views each time. Hide all child views using View.GONE just before starting the animation and change back to VISIBLE once animation finishes (interpolatedTime == 1). This also gives you a nice fade-in effect.

Comment: @OferR I don't see any improvement when using View.GONE for the children. The animation is still very slow!

Comment: @acntwww You can get a smoothly animation multiplying the duration by some factor, like 4. `a.setDuration(((int)(initialHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)) * 4)`

Comment: Although it work, but not smoothly. Tweaking the duration doesn't fix the smoothness.

Comment: Where do I have to call the expand/collapse methods? If I call them inside getChildView and getGroupView , animates the hole group. Is there any way to call them inside the listeners onExpand and onCollapse and animate only the expanded/collapsed group?? Thank you
@TomEsterez

Comment: This won't work on newer APIs, Use `LayoutParams.UNSPECIFIED` when measuring a View not added to layout.

Comment: I changed the duration to 500; I have a view of 30dp height, worked very well, thanks !!

Comment: works like a charm but we could get the original height with getLayoutParams().height before expanding for the first time and then pass it as a parameter to support fixed sizes.

Comment: @Alioo, import android.view.animation.Transformation;

Comment: how can we expand/collapse for specific height with using these methods ?

Comment: but the View's Click event has problem.

Comment: Waring: `GONE` view such as a `TextView` are sure to be measured wrongly by this code, because their height depends on width they can take in parent. Im my case I enclosed my `TextView` in a visible `LinearLayout` with no paddings/margins between them and got `LienarLayout`'s width, and used it in `v.mesaure()`.

Comment: `expand()` should set `v.getLayoutParams().height = 1;` otherwise pre API21 versions of android will cancel the animation and the view will remain hidden.

Comment: Works great! I had problems with measured height as I wanted to expand a fixed dp element, so I changed measure to `v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));` and `v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                        ? targetHeight : (int)(targetHeight * interpolatedTime);` That worked for me!

Comment: I had a trouble with `v.getMeasuredHeight()` returning 0, so I had to pre - measure the view (i. e. `v.getHeight()`) and change the visibility to GONE in the `onGlobalLayout()` of the view and pass the height as a parameter of the `expand(final View v)`method and it works like a charm!

Comment: Took this answer and improved it with a fixed calling of measure() and added a natural interpolator for good measure. See my answer below!

Comment: it works fine but my RelativeLayout expands from height 0, I want to expand it from the height that it already has.

Comment: @Amir what is this size ? do you set a fixed height smaller than content height ?

Comment: @TomEsterez It works smooth in the starting, but in the last it shows expands the layout abruptly and doesnot looks good. Please help

Comment: @GauravArora the calculated `targetHeight` does probably not correspond to the actual height of your view. It might be because of a dynamic content. Difficult to tell. To debug that, you could remove child views one by one to narrow down to the cause of the miscalculation.

Comment: i use the above method but as soon as the animation stops my layout is no more visible

Comment: Nice work around, I also had problem when trying to get the height when my view was a LinearLayout with vertical orientation. My solution for that was: `mDescription.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED))`

Comment: Not working great for list view. Full list view get visible for split second and start animation. Any fix for that ?

Comment: Tried with LinearLayout with some input views. Works smoothly but Im getting a weird behavior where icons that does not belongs to collapsing/expanding view gets blurred on layout collapsing. And those icons gets cleared if i expand the view.

Comment: I think we also should ensure the view height isn't set to 0 (at the begin of the expand animation, where interpolatedTime = 0) because this may display the view fully opened just before the expand animation. I fixed this with : 
`view.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1  ? LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT : Math.max(1, (int)(targetHeight * interpolatedTime));`

Comment: Lovely, it works well for LinearLayout. I noticed glitches when was making the views VISIBLE or GONE before calling methods. I removed them and these methods handle visibility anyway then it worked well. Thanks!

Comment: @TomEsterez Esterez getMeasuredHeight() returns different value in andorid 9 , have u noticed ?

Comment: It does not work with a scrollview inside the view, what could it do?

Comment: It works great for layouts, but not with RecyclerView in it :sweat_smile:

Comment: What to do when the recyclerView is inside then?

Comment: My first issue when I tried it on a horizontal RecyclerView, is that at the end of the animation, as soon as the interpolatedTime got to 1.0 and tried to set the height to WRAP_CONTENT, the view shrunk to almost 0. Changed `v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1 ? LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT : (int)(targetHeight * interpolatedTime);` to `v.getLayoutParams().height = (int)(targetHeight * interpolatedTime);` and it stopped collapsing back. Second problem I had with this is that after expansion, my Recycler looked empty. Solved by adding a v.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I used this solution but my view has two child recycler views. The animation works fine but my recycler views inside the original view looks empty.

Comment: While expanding, it blinks for fraction of seconds. How to solve that?

Answer (score 160):

I stumbled over the same problem today and I guess the real solution to this question is this

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
...
 />
```

***You will have to set this property for all topmost layouts, which are involved in the shift.*** If you now set the visibility of one layout to GONE, the other will take the space as the disappearing one is releasing it. There will be a default animation which is some kind of "fading out", but I think you can change this - but the last one I have not tested, for now.

---

If using this in a RecyclerView item, set the visibility of the view to expand/collapse in [onBindViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)) and call [notifyItemChanged(position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemChanged(int)) to trigger the transformation.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        ...

        holder.list.visibility = data[position].listVisibility
        holder.expandCollapse.setOnClickListener {
            data[position].listVisibility = if (data[position].listVisibility == View.GONE) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
            notifyItemChanged(position)
        }
    }
```

If you perform expensive operations in [onBindViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)) you can optimize for partial changes using [notifyItemChanged(position, payload)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object))

```
private const val UPDATE_LIST_VISIBILITY = 1

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int, payloads: MutableList<Any>) {
        if (payloads.contains(UPDATE_LIST_VISIBILITY)) {
            holder.list.visibility = data[position].listVisibility
        } else {
            onBindViewHolder(holder, position)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        ...

        holder.list.visibility = data[position].listVisibility
        holder.expandCollapse.setOnClickListener {
            data[position].listVisibility = if (data[position].listVisibility == View.GONE) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
            notifyItemChanged(position, UPDATE_LIST_VISIBILITY)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Animating Layout Changes: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html

Comment: It does not work after pressing back button. Any suggestions?

Comment: This works perfectly for expand animation, but for collapse the animation takes place after parent layout is shrink.

Comment: @shine_joseph yeah  i'm using this inside a recyclerview and when collapsing looks really weird :/

Comment: To speed up the animation, you can simply use (in Kotlin) `container.layoutTransition.setDuration(200)`.

Brilliant answer, much cleaner than the custom animation. Saved my day.

Comment: Has someone found a solution for the RecyclerView problem?

Comment: Did not work for me.

Answer (score 143):

I was trying to do what I believe was a very similar animation and found an elegant solution. This code assumes that you are always going from 0->h or h->0 (h being the maximum height). The three constructor parameters are view = the view to be animated (in my case, a webview), targetHeight = the maximum height of the view, and down = a boolean which specifies the direction (true = expanding, false = collapsing).

```
public class DropDownAnim extends Animation {
    private final int targetHeight;
    private final View view;
    private final boolean down;

    public DropDownAnim(View view, int targetHeight, boolean down) {
        this.view = view;
        this.targetHeight = targetHeight;
        this.down = down;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        int newHeight;
        if (down) {
            newHeight = (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
        } else {
            newHeight = (int) (targetHeight * (1 - interpolatedTime));
        }
        view.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
        view.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth,
            int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a typo in the code: the "initalize" method name should be "initialize" or it will not get called. ;) I'd recommend using @Override in the future so this kind of typo gets caught by the compiler.

Comment: I'm doing the following: "DropDownAnim anim = new DropDownAnim(grid_titulos_atual, GRID_HEIGHT, true); anim.setDuration(500); anim.start();" but it's not working. I placed some breakpoints on applyTransformation but they are never being reached

Comment: Ops, got it to work, it's view.startAnimation(a)... Performance isn't very good, but it works :)

Comment: @Seth  Thnx for this class but I cant get it to work by colapsing a view.  Can you take a look[here?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9268365/742030)

Comment: This solution works. I have just a strange problem to me: my animation is not initialized nor triggered unles I touch the listview below the view.  Does it have sth. to do with the parent view measurement?

Comment: This solution would allow me to collapse my (Already expanded) RelativeLayout, but when I tried to use this solution to expand it again, the layout would not expand and the applyTransformation method never even triggered. The solution was to ensure that the height never reached 0 pixels: if (newHeight == 0) newHeight = 1; which I inserted before the setting of the layoutParams

Comment: @Seth Hi, i have a question when i use your class to make collapse it's reset's my TextView to 0 but it's initial height 40dp how can i change your class to work properly

Comment: @IamStalker In that situation, you should probably initialize with two variables, startingHeight and endingHeight. Then change to:               if (down) {
            newHeight = (int) (((endingHeight-startingHeight) * interpolatedTime) + startingHeight);
        } else {
            newHeight = (int) (((endingHeight-startingHeight)* (1 - interpolatedTime))+startingHeight);
        }

Comment: @MattF i'm not sure why that happens, that was not a problem for me

Comment: @Seth I think newHeight can simply be (int) (((targetHeight -startingHeight) * interpolatedTime) + startingHeight), no matter the direction, as long as startingHeight is set in initialize().

Comment: @Giorgos good call. If you are initializing with both a starting height as well as an ending height, the if block is unnecessary.

Comment: At time of collapse view and if view height is more it looks like lagging what can do to make it smooth.

Comment: This code doesn't work when collapsing. You want the height to be a function of the *original* height, not the target height. I used `newHeight = (int) (viewHeight * (1 - interpolatedTime));` where `viewHeight` is the original height of the view, set in the constructor. You might want to edit your original code to fix this.

Answer (score 77):

I took @LenaYan 's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29838619/4398784) that didn't work properly
to me (*because it was transforming the View to a 0 height view before collapsing and/or expanding*) and made some changes.

**Now it works great**, by taking the View's **previous** **height** and start expanding with this size. Collapsing is the same.

*You can simply copy and paste the code below:*

```
public static void expand(final View v, int duration, int targetHeight) {
    
    int prevHeight  = v.getHeight();

    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(prevHeight, targetHeight);
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            v.requestLayout();
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    valueAnimator.setDuration(duration);
    valueAnimator.start();
}

public static void collapse(final View v, int duration, int targetHeight) {
    int prevHeight  = v.getHeight();
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(prevHeight, targetHeight);
    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            v.requestLayout();
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.setDuration(duration);
    valueAnimator.start();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
//Expanding the View
   expand(yourView, 2000, 200);

// Collapsing the View     
   collapse(yourView, 2000, 100);
```

**Easy enough!**

*Thanks LenaYan for the initial code!*

Comment: Though it works, it depends on developer settings (animation duration). If it is disabled, no animation will be shown.

Comment: Yes, but it may or may not be a problem. Depends on your application. You could, for instance, easily make the animation duration be proportional to the expanded/collapsed size with simple changes. Having a settable animation duration gives you a bit more freedom.

Comment: Expand animation not working. it looks like collapse animation.

Comment: How to add fading edge while it  expands/collapse ? Needed something like while expanding bottom lines moves up from underneath .

Comment: Is it important to set DecelerateInterpolator two times in collapse ?

Answer (score 42):

An alternative is to use a scale animation with the following scaling factors for expanding:

```
ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1, 1, 0, 1);
```

and for collapsing:

```
ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1, 1, 1, 0);
```

Comment: how to start the animation.. View.startAnimation(anim); not seems to work

Comment: that's exaclty how I start the animation. Do other animations work for you?

Comment: This does not push down views below it during the animation and appears as if it is stretching the animated view from 0 -> h.

Comment: Btw, view animations work great for scaling: oView.animate().scaleY(0) to collapse vertically; oView.animate().scaleY(1) to open (note it's only available sdk 12 and up).

Answer (score 28):

@Tom Esterez's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4946295/247325), but updated to use view.measure() properly per [Android getMeasuredHeight returns wrong values !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157652/android-getmeasuredheight-returns-wrong-values)

```
    // http://easings.net/
    Interpolator easeInOutQuart = PathInterpolatorCompat.create(0.77f, 0f, 0.175f, 1f);

    public static Animation expand(final View view) {
        int matchParentMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(((View) view.getParent()).getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int wrapContentMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        view.measure(matchParentMeasureSpec, wrapContentMeasureSpec);
        final int targetHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();

        // Older versions of android (pre API 21) cancel animations for views with a height of 0 so use 1 instead.
        view.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Animation animation = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {

               view.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    : (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime);

            view.requestLayout();
        }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        animation.setInterpolator(easeInOutQuart);
        animation.setDuration(computeDurationFromHeight(view));
        view.startAnimation(animation);

        return animation;
    }

    public static Animation collapse(final View view) {
        final int initialHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();

        Animation a = new Animation() {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    view.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int) (initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                    view.requestLayout();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        a.setInterpolator(easeInOutQuart);

        int durationMillis = computeDurationFromHeight(view);
        a.setDuration(durationMillis);

        view.startAnimation(a);

        return a;
    }

    private static int computeDurationFromHeight(View view) {
        // 1dp/ms * multiplier
        return (int) (view.getMeasuredHeight() / view.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }
```

Comment: what is addHeight and DURATION_MULTIPLIER?

Comment: Forgot about those, addHeight is in case you need extra height in your expand (probably not) and DURATION_MODIFIER is just a speed modifier in case you want to speed/slow the animations.

Comment: Works great! One small lag occurs while using TextView with only one word on the last line. And could you explain what the PathInterpolator does..?

Comment: The easeInOutQuart makes the animation slow at first, then fast, then slow at the end for a very natural feeling. They talk about it in depth here http://easings.net/

Comment: i tried your method but whenever the animation ends my view is no longer visible.

Comment: @AmanVerma when you add the view, make sure to specify layout params

Answer (score 27):

Ok, I just found a VERY ugly solution :

```
public static Animation expand(final View v, Runnable onEnd) {
    try {
        Method m = v.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("onMeasure", int.class, int.class);
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(
            v,
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(((View)v.getParent()).getMeasuredHeight(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
        );
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("test", "", e);
    }
    final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
    Log.d("test", "initialHeight="+initialHeight);

    v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            final int newHeight = (int)(initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };
    a.setDuration(5000);
    v.startAnimation(a);
    return a;
}
```

Feel free to propose a better solution !

Comment: +1, even this is named as ugly, it works for a view where we don't know its size yet (e.g. in case we're adding a newly created view (whose size is FILL_PARENT) to the parent and would like to animate this process, including animating the parent size growth).

Comment: BTW, looks like there is a little error in the `View.onMeause(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)` invokation, so width and height specs should be swapped.

Answer (score 23):

```
public static void expand(final View v, int duration, int targetHeight) {
        v.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, targetHeight);
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        });
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.setDuration(duration);
        valueAnimator.start();
    }
public static void collapse(final View v, int duration, int targetHeight) {
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, targetHeight);
    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            v.requestLayout();
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    valueAnimator.setDuration(duration);
    valueAnimator.start();
}
```

Comment: I have this issue...the content inside the collapsible view is disappearing on expansion. I have Recycler View which disappears on expanding this view. @LenaYan

Answer (score 22):

If you don't want to expand or collapse all the way - here is a simple HeightAnimation -

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;

public class HeightAnimation extends Animation {
    protected final int originalHeight;
    protected final View view;
    protected float perValue;

    public HeightAnimation(View view, int fromHeight, int toHeight) {
        this.view = view;
        this.originalHeight = fromHeight;
        this.perValue = (toHeight - fromHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        view.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (originalHeight + perValue * interpolatedTime);
        view.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
HeightAnimation heightAnim = new HeightAnimation(view, view.getHeight(), viewPager.getHeight() - otherView.getHeight());
heightAnim.setDuration(1000);
view.startAnimation(heightAnim);
```

Answer (score 21):

I adapted [the currently accepted answer by Tom Esterez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13381228/930640), which worked but had a choppy and not very smooth animation. My solution basically replaces the `Animation` with a `ValueAnimator`, which can be fitted with an `Interpolator` of your choice to achieve various effects such as overshoot, bounce, accelerate, etc.

This solution works great with views that have a dynamic height (i.e. using `WRAP_CONTENT`), as it first measures the actual required height and then animates to that height.

```
public static void expand(final View v) {
    v.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    // Older versions of android (pre API 21) cancel animations for views with a height of 0.
    v.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(1, targetHeight);
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            v.requestLayout();
        }
    });
    va.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        }

        @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}
        @Override public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
        @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
    });
    va.setDuration(300);
    va.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
    va.start();
}

public static void collapse(final View v) {
    final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialHeight, 0);
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            v.requestLayout();
        }
    });
    va.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}
        @Override public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
        @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
    });
    va.setDuration(300);
    va.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    va.start();
}
```

You then simply call `expand( myView );` or `collapse( myView );`.

Comment: Just corrected the params used in `v.measure()` and now it is working perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting delayed while expanding. Delay is small but visible. Any idea why?

Answer (score 16):

Making use of Kotlin Extension Functions this is tested and shortest answer

Just call animateVisibility(expand/collapse) on any View.

```
fun View.animateVisibility(setVisible: Boolean) {
    if (setVisible) expand(this) else collapse(this)
}

private fun expand(view: View) {
    view.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    val initialHeight = 0
    val targetHeight = view.measuredHeight

    // Older versions of Android (pre API 21) cancel animations for views with a height of 0.
    //v.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
    view.layoutParams.height = 0
    view.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    animateView(view, initialHeight, targetHeight)
}

private fun collapse(view: View) {
    val initialHeight = view.measuredHeight
    val targetHeight = 0

    animateView(view, initialHeight, targetHeight)
}

private fun animateView(v: View, initialHeight: Int, targetHeight: Int) {
    val valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialHeight, targetHeight)
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener { animation ->
        v.layoutParams.height = animation.animatedValue as Int
        v.requestLayout()
    }
    valueAnimator.addListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
            v.layoutParams.height = targetHeight
        }

        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator) {}
        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator) {}
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator) {}
    })
    valueAnimator.duration = 300
    valueAnimator.interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
    valueAnimator.start()
}
```

Comment: I liked this solution until i realized if there's a textview with multiple lines with a height of wrap_content, when expanded, the textview will only show one line. I'm trying to fix now

Comment: I tried this, but the animation does not appear to be smooth. For expand, The whole textview appears at once briefly and then the animation plays. For collapse, the textview immediately expands again right after collapsing, for some reason. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

Adding to Tom Esterez's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13381228/1421879) and Erik B's [excellent update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049412/1421879) to it, I thought I'd post my own take, compacting the expand and contract methods into one. This way, you could for example have an action like this...

```
button.setOnClickListener(v -> expandCollapse(view));
```

... which calls the method below and letting it figure out what to do after each onClick()...

```
public static void expandCollapse(View view) {

    boolean expand = view.getVisibility() == View.GONE;
    Interpolator easeInOutQuart = PathInterpolatorCompat.create(0.77f, 0f, 0.175f, 1f);

    view.measure(
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(((View) view.getParent()).getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
    );

    int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
    int duration = (int) (height/view.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

    Animation animation = new Animation() {
        @Override protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            if (expand) {
                view.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                    view.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                } else {
                    view.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (height * interpolatedTime);
                }
                view.requestLayout();
            } else {
                if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    view.getLayoutParams().height = height - (int) (height * interpolatedTime);
                    view.requestLayout();
                }
            }
        }
        @Override public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    animation.setInterpolator(easeInOutQuart);
    animation.setDuration(duration);
    view.startAnimation(animation);

}
```

Comment: I tried this code but for it tow work on multiple views, you have to scroll. Any idea how I can fix this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/43916369/1009507

Comment: @Ukavi I'm using this with multiple views and it works fine inside a ScrollView.

Comment: What about in a recyclerview?

Comment: @Ukavi haven't had a need to use it in a recyclerview yet but I can't see why it wouldn't work. You'll have to experiment with it yourself a little ;)

Answer (score 8):

For Smooth animation please use Handler with run method.....And Enjoy Expand /Collapse animation

```
    class AnimUtils{

                 public void expand(final View v) {
                  int ANIMATION_DURATION=500;//in milisecond
        v.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final int targtetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

        v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Animation a = new Animation()
        {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                        ? LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        : (int)(targtetHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // 1dp/ms
        a.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);

      // a.setDuration((int)(targtetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
        v.startAnimation(a);
    }



    public void collapse(final View v) {
        final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

        Animation a = new Animation()
        {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                if(interpolatedTime == 1){
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else{
                    v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int)(initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                    v.requestLayout();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // 1dp/ms
        a.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
       // a.setDuration((int)(initialHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
        v.startAnimation(a);
    }
}
```

And Call using this code:

```
       private void setAnimationOnView(final View inactive ) {
    //I am applying expand and collapse on this TextView ...You can use your view 

    //for expand animation
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            new AnimationUtililty().expand(inactive);

        }
    }, 1000);


    //For collapse
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            new AnimationUtililty().collapse(inactive);
            //inactive.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }, 8000);

}
```

Other solution is:

```
               public void expandOrCollapse(final View v,String exp_or_colpse) {
    TranslateAnimation anim = null;
    if(exp_or_colpse.equals("expand"))
    {
        anim = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, -v.getHeight(), 0.0f);
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
    }
    else{
        anim = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -v.getHeight());
        AnimationListener collapselistener= new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        };

        anim.setAnimationListener(collapselistener);
    }

     // To Collapse
        //

    anim.setDuration(300);
    anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(0.5f));
    v.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would like to add something to the very helpful [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5122460/426213). If you don't know the height you'll end up with since your views .getHeight() returns 0 you can do the following to get the height:

```
contentView.measure(DUMMY_HIGH_DIMENSION, DUMMY_HIGH_DIMENSION);
int finalHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Where DUMMY_HIGH_DIMENSIONS is the width/height (in pixels) your view is constrained to ... having this a huge number is reasonable when the view is encapsulated with a ScrollView.

Answer (score 6):

This is a snippet that I used to resize the width of a view (LinearLayout) with animation.

The code is supposed to do expand or shrink according the target size. If you want a fill_parent width, you will have to pass the parent .getMeasuredWidth as target width while setting the flag to true.

Hope it helps some of you.

```
public class WidthResizeAnimation extends Animation {
int targetWidth;
int originaltWidth;
View view;
boolean expand;
int newWidth = 0;
boolean fillParent;

public WidthResizeAnimation(View view, int targetWidth, boolean fillParent) {
    this.view = view;
    this.originaltWidth = this.view.getMeasuredWidth();
    this.targetWidth = targetWidth;
    newWidth = originaltWidth;
    if (originaltWidth > targetWidth) {
        expand = false;
    } else {
        expand = true;
    }
    this.fillParent = fillParent;
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    if (expand && newWidth < targetWidth) {
        newWidth = (int) (newWidth + (targetWidth - newWidth) * interpolatedTime);
    }

    if (!expand && newWidth > targetWidth) {
        newWidth = (int) (newWidth - (newWidth - targetWidth) * interpolatedTime);
    }
    if (fillParent && interpolatedTime == 1.0) {
        view.getLayoutParams().width = -1;

    } else {
        view.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
    }
    view.requestLayout();
}

@Override
public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
    super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
}

@Override
public boolean willChangeBounds() {
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Is there any trick to getting this to work? The class gets the correct original and target widths, but my views won't resize. I'm using `resizeAnim.start()`. Also have tried with and without `setFillAfter(true)`

Comment: Got it. Had to call `.startAnimation(resizeAnim)` on the view.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I agreed with the above comments. And indeed, it does seem like the right (or at least the easiest?) thing to do is to specify (in XML) an initial layout height of "0px" -- and then you can  pass in another argument for "toHeight" (i.e. the "final height") to the constructor of your custom Animation sub-class, e.g. in the example above, it would look something like so:

```
    public DropDownAnim( View v, int toHeight ) { ... }
```

Anyways, hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 5):

combined solutions from @Tom Esterez and @Geraldo Neto

```
public static void expandOrCollapseView(View v,boolean expand){

    if(expand){
        v.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
        v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(targetHeight);
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        });
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.setDuration(500);
        valueAnimator.start();
    }
    else
    {
        final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialHeight,0);
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                v.requestLayout();
                if((int)animation.getAnimatedValue() == 0)
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.setDuration(500);
        valueAnimator.start();
    }
}

//sample usage
expandOrCollapseView((Your ViewGroup),(Your ViewGroup).getVisibility()!=View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Transition` or `Animator` that changes visibility of section to be expanded/collapsed, or `ConstraintSet` with different layouts.

[image]

Easiest one is to use motionLayout with 2 different layouts and constraintSets to change from one layout to another on button click. You can change between layouts with

```
val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
constraintSet.clone(this, R.layout.layout_collapsed)

val transition = ChangeBounds()
transition.interpolator = AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f)
transition.setDuration(300)

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(YOUR_VIEW, transition)
constraintSet.applyTo(YOUR_VIEW)
```

With **Transition** api

**RotateX.kt**

I created the one in gif using Transitions api that change rotationX.

```
class RotateX : Transition {

    @Keep
    constructor() : super()

    @Keep
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    override fun getTransitionProperties(): Array<String> {
        return TRANSITION_PROPERTIES
    }

    override fun captureStartValues(transitionValues: TransitionValues) {
        captureValues(transitionValues)
    }

    override fun captureEndValues(transitionValues: TransitionValues) {
        captureValues(transitionValues)
    }

    override fun createAnimator(
        sceneRoot: ViewGroup,
        startValues: TransitionValues?,
        endValues: TransitionValues?
    ): Animator? {

        if (startValues == null || endValues == null) return null

        val startRotation = startValues.values[PROP_ROTATION] as Float
        val endRotation = endValues.values[PROP_ROTATION] as Float
        if (startRotation == endRotation) return null

        val view = endValues.view
        // ensure the pivot is set
        view.pivotX = view.width / 2f
        view.pivotY = view.height / 2f
        return ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.ROTATION_X, startRotation, endRotation)
    }

    private fun captureValues(transitionValues: TransitionValues) {
        val view = transitionValues.view
        if (view == null || view.width <= 0 || view.height <= 0) return
        transitionValues.values[PROP_ROTATION] = view.rotationX
    }

    companion object {

        private const val PROP_ROTATION = "iosched:rotate:rotation"
        private val TRANSITION_PROPERTIES = arrayOf(PROP_ROTATION)
    }
}
```

create xml file that targets expand button

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <transitionSet
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in">
    
        <transition class="com.smarttoolfactory.tutorial3_1transitions.transition.RotateX">
            <targets>
                <target android:targetId="@id/ivExpand" />
            </targets>
        </transition>
    
        <autoTransition android:duration="200" />
    
    </transitionSet>

My layout to be expanded or collapsed


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="2dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:transitionName="@string/transition_card_view"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivAvatar"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:src="@drawable/avatar_1_raster" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivExpand"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_expand_more_24" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:text="Some Title"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivAvatar"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:textColor="?android:textColorSecondary"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvTitle"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle"
                tools:text="Tuesday 7pm" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvBody"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="@string/bacon_ipsum_short"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivAvatar"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvDate" />


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvBody"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_image_destination" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</layout>
```

And set up visibility of items to collapse or expand

```
private fun setUpExpandedStatus() {
    if (isExpanded) {
        binding.recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.ivExpand.rotationX = 180f
    } else {
        binding.recyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.ivExpand.rotationX = 0f
    }
}
```

And start transition with

```
   val transition = TransitionInflater.from(itemView.context)
            .inflateTransition(R.transition.icon_expand_toggle)

  TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parent, transition)

  isExpanded = !isExpanded
        
  setUpExpandedStatus()
```

I created animation and transitions samples including the one on the gif, you can check them out [there](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Animation-Tutorials).

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution. I think it is simpler. It only expands the view but can easy be extended.

```
public class WidthExpandAnimation extends Animation
{
    int _targetWidth;
    View _view;

    public WidthExpandAnimation(View view)
    {
        _view = view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
    {
        if (interpolatedTime < 1.f)
        {
            int newWidth = (int) (_targetWidth * interpolatedTime);

            _view.layout(_view.getLeft(), _view.getTop(),
                    _view.getLeft() + newWidth, _view.getBottom());
        }
        else
            _view.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight)
    {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);

        _targetWidth = width;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest solution is to set `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to your `LinearLayout` and then just show/hide view by seting its visibility. Works like a charm, but you have no controll on the animation duration

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track.  Make sure you have v1 set to have a layout height of zero right before the animation starts.  You want to initialize your setup to look like the first frame of the animation before starting the animation.

Comment: I agree but how to get initialHeight (required by my animation) if I do this ?

Comment: Have you tried actually just saving the initial height in initialize, setting the view visible there, and then setting v.getLayoutParams().height = 0; directly after, all in initialize?

Comment: Yes, if i do so the initialize method is called with height=0

Answer (score 3):

This is really simple with my [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) library. For starts, consider this layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="View 1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/v2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="View 2" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="View 3" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

We can animate the height to the desired value - say `100dp` - using the following code:

```
//convert 100dp to pixel value
int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Then use `droidQuery` to animate. The simplest way is with this:

```
$.animate("{ height: " + height + "}", new AnimationOptions());
```

To make the animation more appealing, consider adding an easing:

```
$.animate("{ height: " + height + "}", new AnimationOptions().easing($.Easing.BOUNCE));
```

You can also change the duration on `AnimationOptions` using the `duration()` method, or handle what happens when the animation ends. For a complex example, try:

```
$.animate("{ height: " + height + "}", new AnimationOptions().easing($.Easing.BOUNCE)
                                                             .duration(1000)
                                                             .complete(new Function() {
                                                                 @Override
                                                                 public void invoke($ d, Object... args) {
                                                                     $.toast(context, "finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                                                 }
                                                             }));
```

Answer (score 3):

This was my solution, my `ImageView` grows from `100%` to `200%` and return to his original size, using two animation files inside `res/anim/` folder

**anim_grow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
 <scale
  android:fromXScale="1.0"
  android:toXScale="2.0"
  android:fromYScale="1.0"
  android:toYScale="2.0"
  android:duration="3000"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:startOffset="2000" />
</set>
```

**anim_shrink.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
 <scale
  android:fromXScale="2.0"
  android:toXScale="1.0"
  android:fromYScale="2.0"
  android:toYScale="1.0"
  android:duration="3000"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:startOffset="2000" />
</set>
```

Send an `ImageView` to my method `setAnimationGrowShrink()`

```
ImageView img1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
setAnimationGrowShrink(img1);
```

`setAnimationGrowShrink()` method:

```
private void setAnimationGrowShrink(final ImageView imgV){
    final Animation animationEnlarge = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.anim_grow);
    final Animation animationShrink = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.anim_shrink);

    imgV.startAnimation(animationEnlarge);

    animationEnlarge.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            imgV.startAnimation(animationShrink);
        }
    });

    animationShrink.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            imgV.startAnimation(animationEnlarge);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on solutions by @Tom Esterez and @Seth Nelson (top 2) I simlified them. As well as original solutions it doesn't depend on Developer options (animation settings).

```
private void resizeWithAnimation(final View view, int duration, final int targetHeight) {
    final int initialHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
    final int distance = targetHeight - initialHeight;

    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            if (interpolatedTime == 1 && targetHeight == 0) {
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            view.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (initialHeight + distance * interpolatedTime);
            view.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    a.setDuration(duration);
    view.startAnimation(a);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a proper working solution, I have tested it:

Exapnd:

```
private void expand(View v) {
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(PARENT_VIEW.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

    final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, targetHeight);
    mAnimator.setDuration(800);
    mAnimator.start();
}
```

Collapse:

```
private void collapse(View v) {
    int finalHeight = v.getHeight();

    mAnimator = slideAnimator(finalHeight, 0);

    mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            //Height=0, but it set visibility to GONE
            llDescp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

        }
    });
    mAnimator.start();
}
```

Value Animator:

```
private ValueAnimator slideAnimator(int start, int end) {
    ValueAnimator mAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);

    mAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            //Update Height
            int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = llDescp.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = value;
            v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
    return mAnimator;
}
```

View v is the view to be animated, PARENT_VIEW is the container view containing the view.

Answer (score 2):

Best solution for expand/collapse view's:

```
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        View view = buttonView.getId() == R.id.tb_search ? fSearch : layoutSettings;
        transform(view, 200, isChecked
            ? ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            : 0);
    }

    public static void transform(final View v, int duration, int targetHeight) {
        int prevHeight  = v.getHeight();
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ValueAnimator animator;
        if (targetHeight == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
            v.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(prevHeight, v.getMeasuredHeight());
        } else {
            animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(prevHeight, targetHeight);
        }
        animator.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = (animation.getAnimatedFraction() == 1.0f)
                    ? targetHeight
                    : (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            v.requestLayout();
        });
        animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        animator.setDuration(duration);
        animator.start();
    }
```

Comment: Though it works, it also depends on developer settings (animation duration). And polish your code, delete lambda-function and reformat `onCheckedChanged`.

Comment: Why is it sufficient to call requestLayout only on v after changing v's LayoutParams? I thought it'd be necessary to call requestLayout on v's parent

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ViewPropertyAnimator with a slight twist.  To collapse, scale the view to a height of 1 pixel, then hide it.  To expand, show it, then expand it to its height.

```
private void collapse(final View view) {
    view.setPivotY(0);
    view.animate().scaleY(1/view.getHeight()).setDuration(1000).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            view.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
    });
}

private void expand(View view, int height) {
    float scaleFactor = height / view.getHeight();

    view.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    view.setPivotY(0);
    view.animate().scaleY(scaleFactor).setDuration(1000);
}
```

The pivot tells the view where to scale from, default is in the middle. The duration is optional (default = 1000). You can also set the interpolator to use, like `.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())`

Answer (score 1):

I created version in which you don't need to specify layout height, hence it's a lot easier and cleaner to use. The solution is to get the height in the first frame of the animation (it's available at that moment, at least during my tests). This way you can provide a View with an arbitrary height and bottom margin.

There's also one little hack in the constructor - the bottom margin is set to -10000 so that the view stays hidden before the transformation (prevents flicker).

```
public class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {


    private View mAnimatedView;
    private ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mViewLayoutParams;
    private int mMarginStart, mMarginEnd;

    public ExpandAnimation(View view) {
        mAnimatedView = view;
        mViewLayoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        mMarginEnd = mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin;
        mMarginStart = -10000; //hide before viewing by settings very high negative bottom margin (hack, but works nicely)
        mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin = mMarginStart;
        mAnimatedView.setLayoutParams(mViewLayoutParams);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
            //view height is already known when the animation starts
            if(interpolatedTime==0){
                mMarginStart = -mAnimatedView.getHeight();
            }
            mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin = (int)((mMarginEnd-mMarginStart) * interpolatedTime)+mMarginStart;
            mAnimatedView.setLayoutParams(mViewLayoutParams);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ValueAnimator:

```
ValueAnimator expandAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofInt(mainView.getHeight(), 400);
expandAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(final ValueAnimator animation) {
        int height = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) mainView.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = height;
    }
});


expandAnimation.setDuration(500);
expandAnimation.start();
```

Comment: In my case doesn't do anything. Also you may ease your code, collapsing 2 lines into `mainView.getLayoutParams().height = height`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void slide(View v, int speed, int pos) {
    v.animate().setDuration(speed);
    v.animate().translationY(pos);
    v.animate().start();
}

// slide down
slide(yourView, 250, yourViewHeight);
// slide up
slide(yourView, 250, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Animation that either expands or collapses a view by sliding it down to make
 * it visible. Or by sliding it up so it will hide. It will look like it slides
 * behind the view above.
 * 
 */
public class FinalExpandCollapseAnimation extends Animation
{
    private View mAnimatedView;
    private int mEndHeight;
    private int mType;
    public final static int COLLAPSE = 1;
    public final static int EXPAND = 0;
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams mLayoutParams;
    private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mLayoutParamsRel;
    private String layout;
    private Context context;

    /**
     * Initializes expand collapse animation, has two types, collapse (1) and
     * expand (0).
     * 
     * @param view
     *            The view to animate
     * @param type
     *            The type of animation: 0 will expand from gone and 0 size to
     *            visible and layout size defined in xml. 1 will collapse view
     *            and set to gone
     */
    public FinalExpandCollapseAnimation(View view, int type, int height, String layout, Context context)
    {
        this.layout = layout;
        this.context = context;
        mAnimatedView = view;
        mEndHeight = mAnimatedView.getMeasuredHeight();
        if (layout.equalsIgnoreCase("linear"))
            mLayoutParams = ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams());
        else
            mLayoutParamsRel = ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams());
        mType = type;
        if (mType == EXPAND)
        {
            AppConstant.ANIMATED_VIEW_HEIGHT = height;
        }
        else
        {
            if (layout.equalsIgnoreCase("linear"))
                mLayoutParams.topMargin = 0;
            else
                mLayoutParamsRel.topMargin = convertPixelsIntoDensityPixels(36);
        }
        setDuration(600);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
    {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f)
        {
            if (mType == EXPAND)
            {
                if (layout.equalsIgnoreCase("linear"))
                {
                    mLayoutParams.height = AppConstant.ANIMATED_VIEW_HEIGHT
                            + (-AppConstant.ANIMATED_VIEW_HEIGHT + (int) (AppConstant.ANIMATED_VIEW_HEIGHT * interpolatedTime));
                }
                else
                {
                    mLayoutParamsRel.height = AppConstant.ANIMATED_VIEW_HEIGHT
                            + (-AppConstant.ANIMATED_VIEW_HEIGHT + (int) (AppConstant.ANIMATED_VIEW_HEIGHT * interpolatedTime));
                }
                mAnimatedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                if (layout.equalsIgnoreCase("linear"))
                    mLayoutParams.height = mEndHeight - (int) (mEndHeight * interpolatedTime);
                else
                    mLayoutParamsRel.height = mEndHeight - (int) (mEndHeight * interpolatedTime);
            }
            mAnimatedView.requestLayout();
        }
        else
        {
            if (mType == EXPAND)
            {
                if (layout.equalsIgnoreCase("linear"))
                {
                    mLayoutParams.height = AppConstant.ANIMATED_VIEW_HEIGHT;
                    mLayoutParams.topMargin = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    mLayoutParamsRel.height = AppConstant.ANIMATED_VIEW_HEIGHT;
                    mLayoutParamsRel.topMargin = convertPixelsIntoDensityPixels(36);
                }
                mAnimatedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mAnimatedView.requestLayout();
            }
            else
            {
                if (layout.equalsIgnoreCase("linear"))
                    mLayoutParams.height = 0;
                else
                    mLayoutParamsRel.height = 0;
                mAnimatedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mAnimatedView.requestLayout();
            }
        }
    }

    private int convertPixelsIntoDensityPixels(int pixels)
    {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return (int) metrics.density * pixels;
    }
}
```

The class can be called in following way

```
   if (findViewById(R.id.ll_specailoffer_show_hide).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_specialhour_seemore)).setImageResource(R.drawable.white_dropdown_up);

                        FinalExpandCollapseAnimation finalExpandCollapseAnimation = new FinalExpandCollapseAnimation(
                                findViewById(R.id.ll_specailoffer_show_hide),
                                FinalExpandCollapseAnimation.COLLAPSE,
                                SpecialOfferHeight, "linear", this);
                        findViewById(R.id.ll_specailoffer_show_hide)
                                .startAnimation(finalExpandCollapseAnimation);
                        ((View) findViewById(R.id.ll_specailoffer_show_hide).getParent()).invalidate();
                    } else {
                        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_specialhour_seemore)).setImageResource(R.drawable.white_dropdown);

                        FinalExpandCollapseAnimation finalExpandCollapseAnimation = new FinalExpandCollapseAnimation(
                                findViewById(R.id.ll_specailoffer_show_hide),
                                FinalExpandCollapseAnimation.EXPAND,
                                SpecialOfferHeight, "linear", this);
                        findViewById(R.id.ll_specailoffer_show_hide)
                                .startAnimation(finalExpandCollapseAnimation);
                        ((View) findViewById(R.id.ll_specailoffer_show_hide).getParent()).invalidate();
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two simple kotlin extension functions overview.

```
fun View.expand() {
    visibility = View.VISIBLE
    val animate = TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, -height.toFloat(), 0f)
    animate.duration = 200
    animate.fillAfter = true
    startAnimation(animate)
}

fun View.collapse() {
    val animate = TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, 0f, -height.toFloat() )
    animate.duration = 200
    animate.fillAfter = true
    startAnimation(animate)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Keep posting answers :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same code block that have used in accepted answer , But it wont work as same in android 9 , So update the measure according to this

```
v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parentView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parentView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
```

How the constraint works bit different in android 9.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to implement animation,
You can put `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`
to view so that whenever sub view layout change happen,
It will be animated...