# How to scale View / ViewGroup - animate layout in a proper way?

Tags: android, animation, android-layout, layout-animation

In a few words, I want to scale view - in the same way that Android Market does it, when you click the "More" button, on the for examplae 'Description'. 
I figure it out, that the Android Market has the layout of following structure :

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/artists_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/something1"
    android:layout_above="@id/something2"

    >

<!-- Some view there, which height >> 64dip -->

    </FrameLayout>
```

So, I've tried various Animations / LayoutAnimations on the FrameLayout (via `view.setAnimation(), view.setLayoutAnimation()` and `ScaleAnimation`), but the effect is always the same : the view animates, but it's real layout_height after scaling is still the same (so the position of the other views, that depend on the given FrameLayout, remain the same).

After that, I've thought - I change in the loop the layout_height of the given FrameLayout:

```
layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams()
layoutParams.height = scaleTo;
layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

I've it got animating, market-like view, but the cost (performance!!!) is way to high...

So, the question is : Is there any other, proper way to scale (change e.g. height from 50dip to 200dip) the given View / ViewGroup so that the position of the views below the animating view also changes?

Comment: I've been trying to do exactly the same thing. Here's my half-finished attempt: https://gist.github.com/947574 It sets layout params inside a subclass of `Animation`. Performance seemed OK. There are resizing bugs, didn't get to finish--ran out of time budget while hunting down the quirks.

Comment: Also here's similar SO question with similar solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation

Answer (score 1):

As Chet Haase says in this blog post: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html

"...Finally, the previous animations changed the visual appearance of the target objects... but they didn't actually change the objects themselves..."

Since what your need is only visual, instead of changing the view's `LayoutParameters` I would animate the view in the bottom as well with a translate using `android:fillAfter` for both.