# How to expand a layout height with animation?

Tags: android, layout, animation

I couldn't find a good example for how to do this.

I have a RelativeLayout set with x height.

I want to add a button which expands the height to  x+y height.

can someone refer me to a good example on how to do it programmatically?

Comment: Check here for the expand and collapse solution I did:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973089/android-add-view-with-expand-animation-without-blinking

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8162779/5996106 Best solution

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please check below new edited answer as below. But here you need to know the exact new height.

```
public class LayoutAnimationActivity extends Activity {
    RelativeLayout ril1;
    Button btn;
    int initialHeight;
    int actualHeight;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        ril1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
        btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setWidth(100);
        btn.setHeight(200);
        btn.setText("Button");
        actualHeight = 210;
        Ani a = new Ani();
        a.setDuration(2000);
        ril1.startAnimation(a);
    }

    class Ani extends Animation {
        public Ani() {}

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            int newHeight;

            newHeight = (int) (initialHeight * interpolatedTime);

            ril1.removeAllViews();
            btn.setWidth(100);
            btn.setHeight(300);
            btn.setText("as");
            ril1.addView(btn);             
            ril1.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
            ril1.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
            super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
            initialHeight = actualHeight;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: well it expands the layout (I did some changes) but there is no animation

Comment: I don't understand whats the button got to do with all of this. why you removeAllView and the set new width, height and text to the button. this code only expands the layout, how do I collapse it?

Comment: you were the closest. I found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation/5122460#5122460) which helped:

Comment: public class layout_animation extends Activity  - you are code style serial killer

Comment: it works for expansion but to collapse it is not working

Answer (score 74):

You marked the solution that was closest. This is the exact solution. I had the same problem. Hopefully this answer will help others.

Instantiate`ResizeAnimation`

```
ResizeAnimation resizeAnimation = new ResizeAnimation(
     view, 
     targetHeight, 
     startHeight
); 
resizeAnimation.setDuration(duration); 
view.startAnimation(resizeAnimation);
```

`ResizeAnimation` class should look like this

```
public class ResizeAnimation extends Animation {
    final int targetHeight;
    View view;
    int startHeight;

    public ResizeAnimation(View view, int targetHeight, int startHeight) {
        this.view = view;
        this.targetHeight = targetHeight;
        this.startHeight = startHeight;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        int newHeight = (int) (startHeight + targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
        //to support decent animation, change new heigt as Nico S. recommended in comments
        //int newHeight = (int) (startHeight+(targetHeight - startHeight) * interpolatedTime);
        view.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
        view.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!I just modified the newHeight calculation to support also descent  height animation!
int newHeight = (int) (startHeight+(targetHeight - startHeight) * interpolatedTime);

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't make the sliding transition

Comment: Strangely this is not working at all, nothing happens.

Comment: what would be the reverse of it?

Comment: it just only animate height ... can you please tell me how to animate width + height both... i mean expand or shrink animation

Comment: what would be the reverse of it

Comment: thanks for sharing. but I think newHeight in animation should be startHeight  + DeltaHeight * interpolatedTime. Which Delta Height is (target height - start height)

Comment: what is the reverse of it

Comment: This gives performance hiccups to animating view as whole layout is invalidating again.

Comment: Nice , it  wokrs

Answer (score 17):

You need a scale animation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html) is the official documentation

this is in code

```
private void animate() {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation((float)1.0, (float)1.5, (float)1.0, (float)1.5);
    scale.setFillAfter(true);
    scale.setDuration(500);
    imageView.startAnimation(scale); 
}
```

Comment: scaling? i thought I needed translating. i'm adjusting the LayoutParams, are you sure I need scaling?

Comment: If you want to increase the size you need scaling. If you only want to move things you need translation.

Comment: alright, but I need a scale animation that gets starting height and ending height, and not how much to scale

Comment: well if you have 100dip or 100px and you put scale factor of 1 it will make the view 100dip / 100px

Answer (score 6):

Two simple ways to do this without an `Animation` class:

1) Set `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in you xml layout file

2) Use a ViewProperty animator

```
layout.setPivot(0);
layout.animate().scaleY(scaleFactor).setDuration(500);
```

The pivot tells the view where to scale from, default is in the middle, which in my experience is almost never what you want.  The duration is optional (default = 1000).

Answer (score 2):

```
final Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    final CollapseAnimator animator = new CollapseAnimator(topLayout);

    final ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int mHeight = button1.getMeasuredHeight();
            KLog.i("onGlobalLayout() mHeight:" + mHeight);
            animator.setValues(mHeight*2, mHeight);

        }
    };
    button1.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            view.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    button1.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
                    animator.collapse();

                }
            });

        }
    });
```

and class

```
public class CollapseAnimator {
    private View view;
    private boolean collapse=true;
    private int duation=300;
    private int destHeight=300;
    private ValueAnimator animator;
    private int originHeight=0;
    private int from=0;
    private int to=0;


    public CollapseAnimator(View view ) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void setValues(int destHeight,int originHeight){
        this.destHeight = destHeight;
        this.originHeight=originHeight;
        from=originHeight;
        to=originHeight;
    }
    public void collapse(){


        from=to;
        if(collapse){

            to=destHeight;
            collapse=false;
        }else{
            to=originHeight;
            collapse=true;
        }
        KLog.i("from:" + from+",to:"+to);
        animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(from, to);
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = val;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });
        animator.setDuration(duation);
        animator.start();
    }
}
```