# Animation on ImageView width changed

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I'm changing width of ImageView programmatically , is there a way adding an animation into width change ?

First state, Width of ImageView 200dp
 Second state Width of ImageView 400dp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this answer: [Resizing Layouts Programmatically As Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8162779/996313). All you have to do is pass your view and the other parameters to the class.