# Scale view size does not affect position of adjacent views

Tags: android, animation

There are some circle(Custom View) in a vertical layout and I animate height of circles by tapping them .(by property animation)
but enlargement of these views do not affect position of circles before and after them.
how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `scale` animation changes the way a view it's drawn, but it doesn't affect the parent's layout. What you need in this case is to update its `LayoutParams` (via an animation) so that the position of any other controls are adjusted accordingly.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8162779/82788) for an excellent sample.

Comment: I have similar problem, please see my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554613/how-to-adjust-relative-layout-when-zooming-an-item) and help me.