# android hide / show Toolbar does not fill the space bottom

Tags: android, android-actionbar, hide, toolbar, swiperefreshlayout

to make a scrolling animation background is not filled, what am I doing wrong?

I am using
- DrawerLayout
- V7 toolbar
- Pager
- SwipeRefreshLayout
- RecyclerView

Activity

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
```

Fragment pager container

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.squidit.squid.ui.widget.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Fragment content

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/missionSwipeRefresh"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"        
    />
```

Scroll hide

```
private void hideViews() {
    mToolbar.animate().translationY(-mToolbar.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2));
    container.animate().translationY(-mToolbar.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2)).start();        
}
```

Problem:

container rises to the top, but the space occupied by it previously on the bottom is without filling

Ilustration:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-Vxv0Qpz2dqcWp5eDVRbmd3czQ&authuser=0

Comment: Your illustration is not working, it requires permission. Why are you moving whole container along with the toolbar?

Comment: @MichałZ. Please check the link again. I found that my problem is with the drawerlayout, but have not yet decided.

Answer (score -1):

I had almost the same problem. 
After hiding toolbar and status bar my layout looks like
http://i62.tinypic.com/qowvgi.png.

**EDIT**:
You may noticed that translation is not the same as moving view out.
To resize your layout with animation set LayoutParams.height on desired inside ValueAnimator.

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbarHeight = mToolbar.getHeight();
```

and finally

```
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(toolbarHeight, 0);
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            mToolbar.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
            mToolbar.requestLayout();

        }
    });
    anim.start();
```

The code above hides toolbar affecting main layout to expand itself. Idea given from [THAT QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140571/resizing-layouts-programatically-as-animation).

Also make sure that you are using *fitsSystemWindows* in layout which is about to be resize.

```
android:fitsSystemWindows = "true"
```

Comment: Please don't use the answers to post comments.

Comment: @murt - the correct way would be to either gain more reputation (and not muddle the waters of other's questions) or to ask your own question.

Comment: any solution how to remove black space at bottom?