# Android animate view (size of the view increase and then return to normal size) in a layout

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I have attached the image in which one imageview is in large size, and i have to animate this, means one by one size of each view will increase and then return to normal size but at a time only one view is in large size.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to take one parameter where you store object position which is already larger (i hope you are using gridview or recycler view). then check if position exist then first reduce it and then enlarge recent selected position. for animation check here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8162779/2128166