# Expand listView when Flinged in android

Tags: android, listview

I'd like to create ListView that can be expandable.

[image]
[image]

So, i found some method, and set listener in listview.

like this.

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnListViewScrollListener() {
            @Override
            protected void onFlinging() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFlinging");
            }

            @Override
            protected void onScrollFinished() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onScrollFinished");

            }

            @Override
            protected void onScrolling() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onScrolling");
            }
        });
```

and here is OnListViewScrollListener.java

```
public abstract class OnListViewScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    private final String TAG = OnListViewScrollListener.class.getSimpleName();
    int mCurrentVisibleItemCount;

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        if(isValidItemCount()){
            switch (scrollState){
                case SCROLL_STATE_FLING :
                    onFlinging();
                    break;

                case SCROLL_STATE_IDLE :
                    onScrollFinished();
                    break;

                case SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL :
                    onScrolling();
                    break;
            };
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        this.mCurrentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
        Log.d(TAG, "firstVisibleItem,  visibleItemCount, totalItemCount # ["+firstVisibleItem+", "+visibleItemCount+", "+totalItemCount+"]");
    }

    private boolean isValidItemCount() {
        return mCurrentVisibleItemCount > 0;
    }

    protected abstract void onFlinging();
    protected abstract void onScrollFinished();
    protected abstract void onScrolling();
}
```

But i don't know how to expand listview that is include many rows which is photos.

like gallary.

Please let me know that how to expand listview.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140571/resizing-layouts-programatically-as-animation) is an example of how to resize a view with an `Animation`. You can use this for both the expanding and collapsing of the `ListView`.

If you want the `ListView` to display more detail when expanded (bigger photos, etc), you'll need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` and return different view in the adapter, once the animation is completed.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about something like bottom sheet

https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html?utm_campaign=android_launch_supportlibrary23.2_022216&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog#bottom-sheets-persistent-bottom-sheets

This one is already provieded in the support library 23.2