# android animate width and height RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-xml

can i get the

> coordinate x and y of  RelativeLayout

while i animate its from

> MATCH_PARENT to WARP_CONTENT

so i just want the x and y for animate another view inside it 
because i have many `RelativeLayout` as childeren and when i change the parent from `MATCH_PARENT` to `WARP_CONTENT` the position of child changed and mabye be out of screen so i think about take the x and y of parent while animate and minus the child position this make child in same position if parent be `MATCH_PARENT` or `WARO_CONTENT`

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
RelativeLayout mlayout = findViewById(R.id.yourID);

float x = mlayout.getX();
float y = mlayout.getY();
```

Edit: from [Resizing layouts programmatically (as animation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140571/resizing-layouts-programatically-as-animation)

So you need the final height and width, maybe you can make it invisbile, change to WRAP_CONTENT, measure new heigth and width, change back, make visible and animate size with code above to new height and width. 
Dont know a better way unfortunately.

Then animate width:

Instantiate`ResizeAnimation`

```
ResizeAnimation resizeAnimation = new ResizeAnimation(
     view, 
     targetHeight, 
     startHeight,
     targetWidth,
     startWidth
); 
resizeAnimation.setDuration(duration); 
view.startAnimation(resizeAnimation);
```

`ResizeAnimation` class should look like this

```
public class ResizeAnimation extends Animation {
    final int targetHeight;
    final int targetWidth;
    View view;
    int startHeight;
    int startWidth;

    public ResizeAnimation(View view, int targetHeight, int startHeight, targetWidth, int startWidth) {
        this.view = view;
        this.targetHeight = targetHeight;
        this.startHeight = startHeight;
        this.targetWidth = targetWidth;
        this.startWidth = startWidth;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        int newHeight = (int) (startHeight + targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
        int newWidth= (int) (startWidth + targetWidth * interpolatedTime);

        view.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
        view.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
        view.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok but how can i animate thats height and width from `MATCH_PARENT`
to `CONTENT_WARP`

Comment: @medo I guess
`ResizeAnimation resizeAnimation = new ResizeAnimation(view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);`