# Animating view: set translationY to 0 while also scaling

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view, android-transitions

I have a view that I want to animate- scale it to a bigger size and at the same time move to the very top of the screen, just below the notification bar. The problem is however, at least I think, that the **translationY** complies with initial view scale and moves it to the top of the screen, but as the view grows, it gets cut off at top.

This is the code I'm using

```
image.animate()
.alpha(1f)
.translationY(0)
.scaleX(6f)
.scaleY(6f)
.start()
```

Any simple solution to this? A way I could calculate the real value I should set translationY to (based on scale) in order to be positioned correctly? Any help appreciated!

Comment: You can use AnimationSet of Scale and Translate animation to do this.

Comment: This ReSizeAnimation link maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8162779/3674262