# Android: how to change height of fragment with animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I need to implement a fragment which an image view and below that multiple options each with a toggle button and each option have 2 seek bars. So if user disables the toggle button, in that case, that view of 2 seek bar will collapse in such a way that total length of the complete fragment will decrease in the same amount.

So if all the toggle buttons are disabled in starting and a total height of fragment is half of the screen in starting and if a user enables any toggle button, the seek bar view will be visible and height of fragment will also be increased by the same amount. and of course there is a limit on the max height and after that view will scroll.

**Can someone help me if any UI lib is available for this? or any idea how it can be implemented?**

Adding Image for help to understand problem:
[image: **First Image which have one seekbar enabled and view size increased**]

**Above First Image which have one seekbar enabled and view size increased**
[image: **With all seek bars disabled and minimum size**]

**Above Second Image With all seek bars disabled and minimum size**

Comment: Check this link for resizing views. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140571/resizing-layouts-programatically-as-animation

Comment: but it doesn't apply the size reduction on both the view. How to reduce height of complete fragment height and that view height at the same time..

Comment: can't you apply the reduction to the fragment's view too? by using Fragment.getView()

Comment: Set the height of your fragment to WRAP_CONTENT, then as you set the visibility of your views to GONE the height of the fragment should respond accordingly.