# How to I prevent squeeze of item inside layout during scale animation?

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation, xml-layout

I am using scale animation in Android relative layout , where I have a button and need to scale it to small size at one end .

I have used scale animation and it works fine , but it does have an icon which gets squeezed and its shape gets altered .

I want to prevent it and let the button take its shape without affecting the icon shape when it scales from left to right.

How can I achieve this?.

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:fromXScale="1.0"
      android:toXScale="0.1"
      android:fromYScale="1.0"
      android:toYScale="1.0"
      android:duration="100"
      android:pivotX="100%"
       >
   </scale>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't really want a scale animation, you want a resize animation instead.  A scale animation will act like you are resizing an image.  A resize animation should just affect the layout parameters of the view without altering the size of the contents (just the positioning).

You can do this in XML with a property animator:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource#Property

Alternatively, here is an example of a resize animation in code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8162779/342745