# Dynamically change width of a view with animation

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I have a case where have to dynamically change width of a button placed alongside another button in a horizontal linear layout. Button width change depend upon certain condition.

I have already tried many of solutions posted at stackoverflow, but the animation is never smooth. Lags on low-end devices. Some time the text within button seems to be sliding in which I don't want.

Here is what I want to achieve, pls [see here](https://giphy.com/gifs/ZEO6YL3QHqOE2nGljW) how smoothly button width changes in google messages just want to achieve same animation.

Just for reference i've already top voted solutions here, for example [Resizing layouts programmatically (as animation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140571/resizing-layouts-programmatically-as-animation/8162779#8162779)

Comment: does this help? https://medium.com/better-programming/animated-fab-button-with-more-options-2dcf7118fff6

Comment: This is not what i want, this is what i actually want https://giphy.com/gifs/ZEO6YL3QHqOE2nGljW