# Android anim if the width is 0dp

Tags: android, animation

Im try do this...

[image]

The blue is LinearLayout

The red are textviews

The green is a imageview (or view)

How can i do that the object have the same width that the parent?

Comment: Take a look at ScaleAnimations.

Comment: As @dcharm says, check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8063586/1748764