# LayoutParams params - Animation/Duration

Tags: android, animation

I am creating an app in which I expand the view by setting layout params like this:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myview.getLayoutParams();
params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
myview.setLayoutParams(params);
```

It's expanding correctly but I like to do it in smooth way either by setting animation along with params or like to set duration for that expand.

Please help me is it possible to do.

Comment: Have you done any web searches for android view animation?

Comment: Solution like this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8063785/1520438