# How to extend screen layout android

Tags: android, android-layout

-EDIT- THIS QUESTION IS NOT A DUPLICATE. The other methods I have tried does not expand my view to make it a scrollable view with new and old content showing.

What should I be looking for or how should implement this layout if I want my screen to expand vertically on a click of a button. That is for instance:
[image]

Screen 1 has its own content in it whatever it may be, and on the click of a button the screen layout keeps its content (the button goes away) and extends the layout with additional options making it a scrollable listview.

Comment: Are there any views in common between the two layouts?

Comment: You might be able top dip this with two fragments and an animation.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice well, I was thinking it to be one layout? and it expanding with the click of the button. As for views in common, all the views on screen one stays on screen 2. I don't see why I would need to use fragments for this, but if that's the common practice I suppose I could try that.

Comment: Refer this link, I hope it should be help for you...
[How to expand a layout height with animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063466/how-to-expand-a-layout-height-with-animation)