# How to make SlidingDrawer push existing layouts when showing?

Tags: android

Main purpose:
I have a listview display on screen, and want to have a SlidingDrawer on the bottom of it.

I'm actually making the "handle" view of the SlidingDrawer toggle by code to show/hide the drawer.

I want my bar to show by sliding in and "shrink" the listview layout.
And when it hides to make the listview layout return to its original view.

Right now I'm having a listview layout that's fixed in place, and a transparent placeholder for the drawer to show or hide in.

Can someone help me figure this one out ?

Activity xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/Container"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        style="@style/Widget.ListView" />
</LinearLayout>

<include
    layout="@layout/delete_bar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

delete_bar xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/MarginTopBottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <my.WrappingSlidingDrawer
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                style="@style/Widget.Button.Wrap"
                android:id="@+id/btn_DeleteBar_delete"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="@string/w_Delete" />

            <Button
                style="@style/Widget.Button.Wrap"
                android:id="@+id/btn_DeleteBar_cancel"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="@string/w_Cancel" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </my.WrappingSlidingDrawer>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out this answer (and possibly the others with it). It seems they were trying to accomplish something similar. - [Android: Expand/collapse animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation/5122460#5122460)

Answer (score 0):

Try this with default drawer.

```
actionBarToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
            ) {public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
        {
            float moveFactor = (mDrawerList.getWidth() * slideOffset);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
            {
                frameLayout.setTranslationX(moveFactor);
            }
            else
            {
                TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(lastTranslate, moveFactor, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                anim.setDuration(0);
                anim.setFillAfter(true);
                frameLayout.startAnimation(anim);

                lastTranslate = moveFactor;
            }
```

or use different library's for drawing drawer.

Answer (score -1):

i hope this would help u out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FF4444CC">
<SlidingDrawer android:id="@+id/drawer" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:handle="@+id/handle" android:content="@+id/content">

<ImageView android:id="@id/handle" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/tray_handle_normal"`/>

<Button android:id="@id/content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="I'm in here!" />

</SlidingDrawer> </FrameLayout>
```