# Android animation methodology & visibility GONE

Tags: android, animation, android-layout, android-animation

I want to have a small 'header', which when I click it, the rest content is shown with the use of a slide up animation.

I have tried some animations, but the only think I managed was to animate the content inside its parent.. What I want is that when I click the header thing the whole header and the content, which has visibility GONE, to animate up until they are both shown.

Below you may find some screenshots from an app that has this feature(rbb Radios). You can check it below when you click Livestream.

[image]

[image]

Can you give me any insights on how can this be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the way to go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ll check that!

Comment: How about a SlidingDrawer, which does exactly what you described? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html. Bear in mind, that the SlidingDrawer takes up the screen's height by default. So, you would have to specify a specific height for the SlidingDrawer.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `SlidingDrawer` or you can apply the `slide out` & `slide in` animation using `Traslate` animation to the layout also.