# How Do I Set My View LayoutParams Width Smaller?

Tags: android, android-animation, viewgroup, layoutparams

Hi I am borrowing [Seth's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544007/seth) method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5122460/742030) to animate my viewGroups. It works great but in the wrong direction - This is my first time using/extending the Animation class and I cant figure how to decrease the size of my view -This expands it.

Below is the class and how I use it.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class ContainerAnim extends Animation {
    int targetWidth;
    View view;
    boolean opened;

    public ContainerAnim(View v, int targetWidth, boolean opened) {
        this.view = v;
        this.targetWidth = targetWidth;
        this.opened = opened;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        int newWidth;
        if (opened) {
            newWidth = (int) (targetWidth * interpolatedTime);
        } else {
            newWidth = (int) (targetWidth * (1 - interpolatedTime));
        }
        view.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
        view.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth,
            int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
... case R.id.menu_shrink:
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.listFragment_container);

            ContainerAnim set = new ContainerAnim(frame, 100, true);
            set.setDuration(200);
            LayoutAnimationController c = new LayoutAnimationController(set,
                    0.25f);
            frame.setLayoutAnimation(c);
            frame.startLayoutAnimation();

            ft.commit();
...
```

Comment: what happens when you change (targetWidth * interpolatedTime) to (targetWidth / interpolatedTime)  in apply transformation?

Comment: @Paul Nikonowicz The view expands and then returns to the original width

Comment: how about making new width -= 10 so hat the width shrinks?

Comment: @Paul Nikonowicz I've tried that too.  You would think the view would shrink to 10dp but it expands 10 pixels...?

Comment: i mean do it like this: view.getLayoutParams().width -= 10

Comment: @Paul Nikonowic Yea thnx; it expands still. I did find if I remove the layoutWeight in the XML file it works with my original class above but the children doesnt replace the lost space.

Comment: if all else fails, create a different view with less styling information and see if it works. try to make it work in a simple situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've mixed up the usage of that third parameter (the boolean). You call it "opened", and pass it true, because you want to shrink it. However, this is the opposite of the usage in my original code! In my code, the boolean was true if the view was **closed** but I wanted it to **grow**.

"and d = a boolean which specifies the direction (true = expanding, false = collapsing)."

If you swap the condition in the animation class to if(!opened){}, it should work. Or pass it false instead of true. Or pass it true, but change the variable to "closed" instead of "opened".

-Seth