# Android ViewAnimator Expand Height

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a ListView where each item has multiple Views in it.  I want to show / hide one of the items when the user clicks on it.  I have this working and I have the ListView adjusting itself appropriately.  Now I want to animate it and that's where I'm running into problems.  I want to have the hidden view's height expand from 0 to the actual height.  I don't see any way to do this with ViewAnimator.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer on StackOverflow that was exactly what I needed.  I basically had to override the Animation class and do the work myself.  The answer that I referenced is here:  [Android: Expand/collapse animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation)