# Android animation for dynamically loaded image

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation

I want to create an animation for an image that is loaded into a vertical linear layout dynamically.  When triggered I would like the image to slide down with its alpha set to 0 (this will slide all content below it down I hope) then fade the image in.  Being new to Android animations I am having some trouble.  Right now I'm trying to get just the fade in to work, here is what I have:

fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<alpha
    xmlns:android="https://chemas.android.com/ap/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/anticipate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="5000" >
</alpha>
```

In the Activity:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in);

ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
image.setAlpha(0);

((ViewGroup) view).addView(image, 0);

image.startAnimation(animation);
```

The image is being loaded as all the context below it is shifted down, however if never fades in.  I would like to get this working as well as having the image slide down so the dynamica add does not look so choppy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the `xmlns:android` tag.

It should be

`xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

With that being corrected, just remove the `image.setAlpha(0);` and it should animate. I am afraid I cannot give you a reason why it doesn't work with the alpha attribute set to 0.

Regarding the slide down animation, you will have to subclass `Animation`. Have a look at this answer that I think can help you get what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5122460/871102

Comment: Thanks for the info - so the typo made the animation work, however instead of fading in over 5 seconds the the view waits 5 seconds then the alpha changes instantly from 0 to 100.  Any cure for this?

Comment: That is because of the interpolator. In your case I would use `android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"`. An interpolator defines how the animation changes through time.

Comment: Thx @Xavi, that fixed it, now to make it slide down.