# How to animate height of ListView item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I need to animate a ListView item by Y axis from 100% to 0% in 3 sec. This animation should indicate that item was deleted. While the animation item content should be changed to undelete note. I can apply my animation to list item content and it is works great, but item itself keeps its height. 
Any suggestions? Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729830/expand-listview-item-with-animation), but it seems useless.

Comment: have you considered ditching listview altogether for RecyclerView? It's designed to make this type of thing possible and elegant.

Comment: if its feasible, you can notifydataset listener after the animation so that the deleted row is 100% gone.

Comment: @SamDozor see my upd: i need some time to show undelete warning

Comment: check out this tutorial about custom ListView with animations , i hope it helps you http://www.tutozone.info/2014/10/tutoriel-animations-listview-sous.html

Answer (score 0):

i dont know which animation u are using,
but maybe u can use animation listener.
when animation-end callback called, delete item from array if `undlete` flag is not set, then notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: Problem is my animation doesnt animate list item height

Comment: i found it might be similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009642/listview-animate-single-item