# How to create a floating action button (FAB) in android, using AppCompat v21?

Tags: android, xml

I would like to create a floating action button (to add items to a listview), like google calendar, maintaining compatibility with pre-lollipop Android versions (before 5.0).

I created this layout:

Activity main_activity.xml:

```
<LinearLayout ... >

     <include
         layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

     <RelativeLayout ... >

     <!-- My rest of the layout -->

          <!-- Floating action button -->
          <ImageButton style="@style/AppTheme"
                     android:layout_width="60dp"
                     android:layout_height="60dp"
                     android:text="New Button"
                     android:id="@+id/button"
                     android:src="@drawable/ic_fab"
                     android:background="@drawable/fab"
                     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                     android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                     android:layout_marginRight="24dp"/>

     </RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Drawable fab.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#ffa48bc0"/>
</shape>
```

Style styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#ff1d79b1</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ff084d95</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The result is similar, but there isn't the shading, a characteristic of material design:

Calendar's floating action button:

[image: Calendar's floating action button]

My app's floating action button:

[image: My app's floating action button]

How can I add the shading to my button?

I have already used the attribute elevation, but does not work

Comment: The elevation API is Lollipop-only, did you try on a Lollipop device?

Comment: It's probably time you accept one of the given answers.

Comment: In fact, on my 4.4.2 Samsung Galaxy S III, the shadow is there, thanks to AppCompat.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

There is no longer a need for creating your own FAB nor using a third party library, it was included in AppCompat 22.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html

Just add the new support library called design in in your gradle-file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

...and you are good to go:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_happy_image" />
```

Comment: how do you change the background color?

Comment: By default the background color will be the "colorAccent" from your theme. However you can also use floatingActionButton.setRippleColor(color), don't let the name 'ripple' scare you, it works on pre-lollipop devices also.

Comment: I dont have colorAccent, and if I add one and set the color to something else it doesnt work - color sticks to green / turquise.

Comment: I was using a third party for this. Really helped me a lot. 
Thanks. 
One issue with this is, it still feels like its not developed completely.

Comment: Does this work in android lollipop? Floating action bar hides at the bottom and working fine in lower version! Why is it so?

Comment: Yes this works in lollipop. It's very difficult to help without seeing your code, I suggest you post a question with details about your implementation. @RethinavelPillai

Comment: Do you know how to make expanding up smaller buttons for sub-actions?

Comment: I Guess you could for instance put a bunch of mini FABs in a LinearLayout. Just make sure the size of the FABs match the material design pattern: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button

Comment: Thx! any examples with animation on expand? :) (like in Evernote)

Comment: I'm afraid I have no examples at the moment. However, I think you should be able to make some cool animations with the help of a CoordinatorLayout and Behaviors, so keep an eye out for examples involving those.

Comment: yep, expandOrCollapse method works with LinearLayout filled with additional buttons
from here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23932782/2842750

Comment: Here's a great example for using out-of-the-box widget for FAB http://www.technotalkative.com/part-1-floating-action-button/

Comment: @Jjang @user1354603 from docs `The background color of this view defaults to the your theme's colorAccent. If you wish to change this at runtime then you can do so via setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList).`

Comment: For changing background color, use app:backgroundTint="@color/yourcustomcolor" and not rippleColor

Answer (score 43):

I've generally used xml drawables to create shadow/elevation on a pre-lollipop widget. Here, for example, is an xml drawable that can be used on pre-lollipop devices to simulate the floating action button's elevation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:top="8px">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#08000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="3px"
                    android:left="3px"
                    android:right="3px"
                    android:top="3px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#09000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="2px"
                    android:left="2px"
                    android:right="2px"
                    android:top="2px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#10000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="2px"
                    android:left="2px"
                    android:right="2px"
                    android:top="2px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#11000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#12000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#13000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#14000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#15000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#16000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#17000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

In place of `?attr/colorPrimary` you can choose any color. Here's a screenshot of the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I was dreading digging up the XML code again to re-create this.

Comment: I implemented just now and it is great, there is only one weird thing. It seems that when you rotate the phone the shadow/elevation is getting lost. Any thoughts on that? Thanks in advance Justin

Comment: @AmilcarAndrade that's a good question. I have encountered similar things with other xml drawables, but I was actually extracting a bitmap from the drawable itself. To solve that, I essentially used the drawable as a singleton; set once so it isn't drawn again. Perhaps you can get the drawable as a static variable and set it as the background in onCreate?

Comment: Also I added an enhancement you can add a riple effect really easy, below is the code.

Comment: Thanks Justin, I will try your suggestion. Thanks again mate.

Comment: For future references, this is a great example for avoiding the shadows and elevations --> http://www.curious-creature.com/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/comment-page-1/

Comment: i notice the shadow issue only happen to lolipop, could you provide some example for this problem?

Comment: @Eric I'm not exactly sure what you're asking for. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The last 7 shapes are at same location from all sides i.e 1 px. isn't the first 6 shapes get hide by the seventh one i.e `<solid android:color="#17000000"/>` Can you please the purpose of creating seven ovals layers at same position?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar it's kind of interesting how the `<padding/>` attribute works in a layer list. Rather than each shape acting as a sibling to the others, each subsequently defined shape acts as a child of the previously defined shape when it comes to padding. In additional, each subsequently defined shape is drawn above the previously defined shape. So padding of 1px on the first shape means that its borders will be 1px outside the borders of the next shape even though the next shape is drawn above it.

Answer (score 20):

There are a bunch of libraries out there add a FAB(Floating Action Button) in your app, Here are few of them i Know.

[makovkastar's FAB](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton)

[futuersimple's Composite FAB](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button)

[Material Design library which includes FAB too](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary)

All these libraries are supported on pre-lollipop devices, minimum to api 8

Answer (score 8):

Here is one aditional free [Floating Action Button library for Android](https://github.com/Scalified/fab)
It has many customizations and requires SDK version 9 and higher

[image]

[Full Demo Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skSApXvi4xM)

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers

Answer (score 4):

@Justin Pollard xml code works really good. As a side note you can add a ripple effect with the following xml lines.

```
    <item>
    <ripple
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight" >
        <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
            <shape android:shape="oval" >
                <solid android:color="#FFBB00" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval" >
                <solid android:color="@color/ColorPrimary" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </ripple>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [this library](https://github.com/shamanland/floating-action-button), it supports shadow, there is `minSdkVersion=7` and also supports `android:elevation` attribute for `API-21` implicitly.

Original post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25739038/1891118).

Answer (score 0):

Add padding and elevation:

```
 android:elevation="10dp"
 android:padding="10dp"
```