# How to add a library to my project on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, libraries

To resolve my previous question ([How to create a floating action button (FAB) in android, using AppCompat v21?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963219/how-to-create-a-floating-action-button-fab-in-android-using-appcompat-v21) ), i found a nice library here: http://android-arsenal.com/details/1/824 , and i downloaded a .zip file.
The web site contains some instructions about the use of the library, but not how to add it to the project with Android Studio (for example: where to copy the downloaded files, and what files i need to copy)

It is the first time that i use a library, and i don't know what i to do.
How do I put it to my project?

Comment: Here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well this was a problem I faced few days back.
Follow the steps and it will definitely work.

STEP 1:

- Extract the JAR File from the library and keep it in the Desktop.

STEP 2:

- In Android Studio, on the left side,There is a Directory View. There is a dropdown menu on top, which has three choices. **Project, Packages** and **Android** - choices. Select the '**Project**' section.
- Now under that, you will find two Folders - '**Your Application**' and '**External Libraries**'.
- Click on ur Application name and under that, click on the '**app**' folder.
- Now under that there is a folder called '**libs**'. This is the folder where you will paste the JAR file you extracted.

Step 3:

- Paste the **JAR** file inside the '**libs**' folder.
- After that there is one more important step.

Step 4:

- Right-click on the file that you pasted on the 'libs' folder and select the option '**Add As Library**'.
- Then a popup will appear asking to create the library.
- Under 'Add to Module', select 'App'.
- Then press ok.

Wait for a while for the Gradle to build it.
After that , Enjoy.
Your new Library is available in your 'imports'.

Comment: Simple and works perfectly for me in Studio 1.2.1. This should be the accepted asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

It's is very simple: Follow the instruction below

1. copy the line below and navigate to build.gradle file on your project & the open it.
   compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.2.0'
2. Paste the copied text here:

dependencies {
   ............................
   compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.2.0'
   ............................
 }

3. Click the sync gradle file icon on the toolbar. [image]
4. Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you just drag and drop the library to the AS project. you have to unzip first to have a .jar file.
If you want to use Maven you have to add the dependencies to the gradle.