# How to create some thing like gmail compose in android app

Tags: java, android

How I can create some thing like this? Has it any specific name or view? Like red cycle image in below link:

[image]

Comment: It is called `FAB` (**F**loating **A**ction **B**utton) and is part of the `appcompat` support library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create that view using a ListView like its explained there: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html.

You can create the floating button using an oval shape with an image inside and set some elevation. Click here for more info [How to create a floating action button (FAB) in android, using AppCompat v21?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963219/how-to-create-a-floating-action-button-fab-in-android-using-appcompat-v21)

Have a look at general Android Material Design Guidelines to get some additional insight for these kind of ui. https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful for you. I made a "dummy" Gmail UI for show a material activity transition. https://github.com/coyarzun89/FabTransitionActivity