# Extending Buttons (FAB)

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

I need to create something similar to this. This may be duplicate, I'm not sure how to search for this. If you press plus it will extend more buttons

[image: Not Active]
[image: Active]

Best Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a floating action button (FAB) in android, using AppCompat v21?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963219/how-to-create-a-floating-action-button-fab-in-android-using-appcompat-v21)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no longer a need for creating your own FAB nor using a third party library, it was included in AppCompat 22.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html

[How to create a floating action button (FAB) in android, using AppCompat v21?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963219/how-to-create-a-floating-action-button-fab-in-android-using-appcompat-v21)