# setElevation() not working programmatically for floating action button

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

I have implemented floating action with list item and setting elevation from layout and run time on bind data as well. Then following issues occur:

1. fab elevation showing on first item only that is from xml resource I think.
2. `setElevation()` not working run time.
3. `fab show()/hide()` also not working with scale animation.

xml code is here:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_btn_video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/parentLayout"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_av_videocam"
            app:elevation="@dimen/fab_shadow"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963219/how-to-create-a-floating-action-button-fab-in-android-using-appcompat-v21

Comment: @Techidiot i'm using official library fab. the issue is shadow not showing run time.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to change elevation:

```
fab.setCompatElevation(8f); //API>=21
```

You can try to use `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton` instead of `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`. This will allow you to use `show()` and `hide()` methods.