# Dynamic Animation - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I currently have a button that when clicked an animation begins that shows a LinearLayout above the button. The LinearLayout is directly above it. In the xml file the LinearLayouts visibility is set to GONE. So when the button is clicked the visibility is set to VISIBLE. Then the animation begins. The animation is a slidedown animation. Everything works perfectly. But When the button is clicked the button jumps to the bottom of where the LinearLayout ends. Even though the LinearLayout is still going through the animation. How can I make the button move with the LinearLayout animation? I want everything to be a smooth transition. But the button jumps and it doesn't look very smooth.

**LInearLayout Animation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- slide down -->
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a very similar situation today.

I used a custom animation that re sizes the view.

The required height is measured and saved. Initially the height is set to 0 and it grows as the animation goes on. Finally it reaches the measured height and then it is set to wrap content as it was originally.

```
public static void expand(final View v) {
    v.measure(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    : (int)(targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration((int)(targetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

v should be the LinearLayout you would like to animate.
You can choose a fixed time duration if you preffer.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13381228/1646326

Answer (score 0):

Use custom animation, it's very easy you can change whatever you want in applytransformation, 
interpolatedTime - this is current position like in % from start to end animation (and has float value from 0 to 1, so here using this interpolatedTime you can iterate anything you can imagine) ;)

```
static class HeightAnimation extends Animation{
        private View view;
        private int mViewHeightFrom;
        private int mViewHeightTo;



        public HeightAnimation(View view, int heightFrom, int heightTo){
            this.view = view;
            this.mViewHeightFrom = heightFrom;
            this.mViewHeightTo = heightTo;

        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int)((mViewHeightTo - mViewHeightFrom)*interpolatedTime+0.5));
            view.setLayoutParams(params);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isFillEnabled() {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and the usage:

```
public static void applyAnimationHeightTransformation(Context context, View view, int viewHeightFrom, int viewHeightTo, int duration, int animationOffsetMilisec){
        HeightAnimation anim = new HeightAnimation(view, viewHeightFrom, viewHeightTo);
        anim.setStartOffset(animationOffsetMilisec);
        anim.setDuration(duration);
        //anim.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator()); // here interpolators can be used
        if(view != null) {
            view.setAnimation(anim);
            view.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }
```

for height to make easier using - use values in dp via transform to pixels:

```
public static int dpToPx(int dp) {
        return (int)(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, YourApplication.getMainContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    }
```