# How to hide a view from bottom to top with animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have tried the code below:

```
final View v = txt; //txt is my textview
Animation anim = new Animation() {
  protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation animLinear) {
    super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, animLinear);
    // Do relevant calculations here using the interpolatedTime that
    // runs from 0 to 1
    v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) (500 * interpolatedTime)));
  }
};
anim.setDuration(1500);
v.startAnimation(anim);
```

It shows the layout line by line as you go down the view. I want a similar effect but in a reverse manner. In short, I want to show an animation wherein a `TextView` is hidden from bottom to top line by line. I do not want a sliding effect. I wanna hide a view line by line.

Comment: Here is the ans : 
    [solution according to my requirements][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation

Answer (score 1):

Use This Code in Xml

```
 <scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />
```

Comment: It squeezes up the view rather then directly disappearing it

Comment: Here is the ans : 
    [solution according to my requirements][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation