# How to stop an animation (from ObjectAnimator)

Tags: android, android-animation

Below is the code belonging to my activity where I have a button (someButton) which, when clicked, starts an animation on another view, more specifically, a progressbar view, on that same activity:

```
// [...]
someButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressView, "progress", 0, 2000);
        animation.setDuration(2000);
        animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animation.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                // some code to execute when the animation ends
            }
        });
        animation.start();
    }
});
// [...]
```

Now, at some point I may need to stop that progress bar view's animation (when the user taps a stop button, for example). I called `progressView.clearAnimation()` to stop the animation but got no success. I have also noticed that progressView.getAnimation() returns null... 
And when I make `ObjectAnimator animation` variable final and move it outside the `someButton.setOnClickListener`, so that I can access it later to stop the animation, I get the following exception when I tap on someButton (just like what happens [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105843/choreographer-nullpointerexception)):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.setupSetterAndGetter(PropertyValuesHolder.java:505)
   at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.initAnimation(ObjectAnimator.java:487)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:517)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:936)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:946)
   at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:465)
   at android.animation.AnimatorSet$1.onAnimationEnd(AnimatorSet.java:579)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:1056)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.access$400(ValueAnimator.java:50)
[...]
```

And the code that throws that exception is:

```
// [...]

final ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressView, "progress", 0, 2000);
animation.setDuration(2000);
animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
animation.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        // some code to execute when the animation ends
    }
});

someButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        animation.start();// NPE occurs here!
    }
});
// [...]
```

What am doing wrong here?? How can one stop that animation???

Comment: see `cancel` and `end` methods

Answer (score 2):

you can use this way:

```
valueAnimator?.removeAllUpdateListeners()
valueAnimator?.removeAllListeners()
valueAnimator?.end()
valueAnimator?.cancel()
valueAnimator = null
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can Check [this link](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.animation.ObjectAnimator) for better examples.

I would also suggest you to not stop animation (Unless you're implementing it right with Extended view, handlers with postDelay and thread sleeps.
If some logic is done just remove the view/open another screen , specially if it progressView, it doesn't need to be shown but not spinning, just remove it's visibility.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

**Try:** `animation.setCurrentPlayTime(0);`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
anim.cancel();
anim.end();
anim.removeAllListeners();
```