# Show layout like google agenda

Tags: android

A picture from google agenda is more meaningful

[image]

I'm trying to mimic google agenda when user expands layout by clicking on the arrow (near month). The schedule of the month appears with animation and pushes the other layout. I have no idea how to reproduce this and my searches are not successful.

(For information, I use toolbar and I can detect click on month name.)

Can you provide me a path to follow ?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if you're transiting to another fragment/activity or you just want to "expand" some of your views. In the first case, you may want to have a look at [Shared Element](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html) transitions, in the latter some [Custom animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation) would be enought to animate your views.

Consider "reveal" animation, introduced with 5.0 material.

Comment: I think reveal animation is what I want. Thx