# View animation in android for open and close

Tags: android, animation

I am working on android application in which on button click i am giving width and height to my linear layout to make it full screen and by clicking again i am giving its width and height to 1dp. I just need to animate this thing like when i press the button it will slowly animate to full screen and on again pressing of button it will slowly animate to 1dp width and height. I have used translate for this thing but it didn't work in this scenario.

```
btnResize.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            if(resize==true){
                                otherLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(1, 1));
                                resize=false;
                            }else{
                                resize=true;
                                int height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                                int width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

//                              ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
//
//                              Animation animZoomin = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.zoom_in);
//
//                              imageView.startAnimation(animZoomin);
                                otherLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
                            }


                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scale animation:

- Start by calculating your screen size: [Get screen dimensions in
  pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels)
- Next get the current view width and height.
- Calculate the ratio between the 2 to get the scale factor (hint: screenH / viewH)
- Next use view.animate().scaleX(xRatio).scaleY(yRatio) to start the
  animation

You may need to translate the view too if it is not centered in the screen

Other option is to use this method: [Expand/collapse animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation)