# Android How to animate AppBar height changes?

Tags: android, floating-action-button, appbar, android-appbarlayout

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When I click `Floating Action Button`, I want to change height of `app_bar` from `wrap_content` to `180dp`, with smooth animation, and show a new FAB with  I don't know if `CollapsingToolbarLayout` can help? And how to do it?

Comment: Should be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation