# Expand/Collapse Animation: Small lag || MeasureSpec returns wrong value

Tags: android, android-animation

I use the below two methods ([inspired/copied from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049412)) to `expand` and `collapse` some `TextViews` in a `ScrollView` by clicking on the "header"-`TextView`.

Pseudo layout structure:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
            <!-- some other stuff here -->
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView "header1"/>
        <View "fancydivider"/>
        <TextView "content1">
        <TextView "header2"/>
        <View "fancydivider"/>
        <TextView "content2">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Divider is a simple `View`, `height`set to `1dp`. The content-`TextViews` style includes:

```
    <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
```

and some margin & padding.

Methods here:

```
public static void expand(final View v) {

    //v.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    int matchParentMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(((View) v.getParent()).getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    int wrapContentMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    v.measure(matchParentMeasureSpec, wrapContentMeasureSpec);

    final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    // Older versions of android (pre API 21) cancel animations for views with a height of 0.
    v.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    : (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime));
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    a.setInterpolator(easeInOutQuart);
    a.setDuration(computeDurationFromHeight(v));
    v.startAnimation(a);

}

public static void collapse(final View v) {
    final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int) (initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    a.setInterpolator(easeInOutQuart);
    a.setDuration(computeDurationFromHeight(v));
    v.startAnimation(a);
}

private static int computeDurationFromHeight(View view) {
    // 1dp/ms * multiplier
    return (int) (view.getMeasuredHeight() / view.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density) * 4;
}
```

**Problem here:** Everything works fine - until the `expand animation` reaches the last line of text - if there are too few `characters` on it, then it *lags*, jumps, explodes? - however you want to call it - until fully expanded.

`Collapsing` seems to work fine.

I tried other `Interpolator` values, another multiplier in method `computeDurationFromHeight`.

Some testing:

- 4 lines, on fourth line everything more than 17 chars works fine, fewer than 18 chars and it lags.
- 3 lines and irrelevant amount of chars on the last line working fine.
- sometimes the `animation` works on first `expand`, but not on second.
- It seems that the `TextView` gets calculated wrong. With a high `multiplier` I have seen some `text` plopping up for < 0.5s over the next header `TextView`
- removing the `smoothScrollTo` in `expand` does not change anything (except scrolling of course..)
- other interpolators also have 'hiccups', but shorter

**important:**

some Logging in `applyTransformation` (see below) got me to the point, that I see that `final height` is printed **twice** - with exactly 50 points(pixels? dp?) difference. `//smoothly increasing height and then:`
`final height = 202 height = 252 final height = 252` While I get `targetHeight = 203` - so the `height` gets calculated wrong first, but then some magic happens?

---

```
@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    : (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
    v.requestLayout();

    scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? v.getHeight() : (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime));

    Log.d("Anim", "height = " + v.getHeight());
    if (interpolatedTime == 1){
        Log.d("Anim", "final height = " + v.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out what I am missing?

Comment: is there a reason you're checking if the interpolated time = 1, then setting the height to WRAP_CONTENT? Why do this? Why not just say that the height always equals to interpolatedTime * targetHeight? When interpolated time = 1, then the height will be targetHeight as you desire. I think setting the height to WRAP_CONTENT at the end is what's causing the stutter.

Comment: I took that line from the answer linked above - if I only use `interpolatedTime * targetHeight` the last line is not printed at all. I already found the problem is caused by wrong calculation of the `height`.. :/

Comment: `v.requestLayout();` makes the view parent call layout() method and all children being layout again. Consecutive calls might lead to lags. Attempt to animate the Rect instead of the layout params.

Comment: There is only one lag, like a 'hiccup'. Is there any other way making this animation possible? @NikolaDespotoski

Comment: apply this  v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

Comment: @Amy Have you found the source of the problem? I didn't see you comment on any of the answers

Comment: Currently not at work. Next week ;)

Answer (score 0):

it may cause because expending the last element might trigger scrolling because the height of the layout getting bigger, therefore 'push' the display down

try to add a FrameLayout at the bottom with height of 20dp and try to observer if it makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99% sure that you need to change `<item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>` (of the `TextView` being animated) to be `wrap_content` and set it's initial state to `GONE` (as this is you final state after the collapse animation).