# Android PopupWindow Custom Java Animation

Tags: android, animation, android-popupwindow

I want to show/hide a popupwindow using a expand/collapse animation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13381228/5528269).
I was able to use the animation by applying it to the popup view which is a view inside popupwindow. The problem I'm facing now is that when user touches outside popupwindow, popupwindow automatically dismisses and I cannot show collapse animation before dismissing the Popup.

Here is the code I have written:

```
View popupView = View.inflate(context,R.layout.popuplayout, null);
popup = new PopupWindow(popupView,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
popup.setAnimationStyle(0);
popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popup.setFocusable(true);
popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
popup.showAsDropDown(anchor, 0, 0);
popup.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
popupView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            expand(popupView);
    }
});
.
.
.
private void expand(final View v) {
    final int targetHeight = ((View)v.getParent()).getHeight();
    // Older versions of android (pre API 21) cancel animations for views with a height of 0.
    v.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                    : (int)(targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };
    a.setDuration(200);
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

I was wondering whether there is a way to show an animation before dismissing popup on touching outside without xml style or implement the given animation using xml animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class PopupWindowCustom extends PopupWindow{
   public dismiss(){
     View view = getCustomView();
     expand(view);
     super.dismiss();
   }

   private expand(View view){
     //do some anim
   }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but got and idea for doing it :) Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This is how you should do it,

1)Create Two Different set of animations.

say, **popup_show.xml** and **popup_hide.xml** and add it to your **anim** folder which you have to create inside **res** folder.

2)Now inside **values** folder create a xml called **styles.xml** and add these animations to it like this,

```
<style name="Animation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/popup_show</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/popup_hide</item>
</style>
```

3)Now set this style to your `PopupWindow` animation,

```
 popup.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animation);
```

Now it automatically detects Window Enter and Exit and provides with the required animation.
according to Andro Selva.

Comment: I think it's not useful because there is no way to implement my custom animation in xml animations. So NO way to create popup_show and popup_hide animations that can expand/collapse a view without scaling. btw Thanks for answer.