# How to smoothen Linear layout height animation, having heavy content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-linearlayout

```
Animation animation = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = slidingPane.getLayoutParams();
            int calculatedHeight = expandedHeight - ((int) (expandedHeight * interpolatedTime));
            if (calculatedHeight <= collapsedHeight) {
                calculatedHeight = collapsedHeight;
            }
            params.height = calculatedHeight;
            slidingPane.setLayoutParams(params);
            slidingPane.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }

    };
    animation.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
    animation.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
    slidingPane.startAnimation(animation);
```

`SlidingPane` is a `LinearLayout` and it has a `ListView` as a child. `ListView` contains images in every row. 
Now this code is working absolutely fine, **but animation is not smooth**. If I remove images from listview then it works fine. 
I have already tried following things based on the answers on SO on similar questions - 

 1. Hide the content of sliding pane before animation and then again make them visible on animation end. It helps but behavior looks very odd
2. Set `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in xml, but its not animating anything

Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: try to set Interpolator in animation like: animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

Comment: @Mehta Can you please post the whole code. I didnt get much idea by that single line :)

Comment: check this for expand animation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34714434/4628611

Comment: @Mehta I used the above mentioned code but it has poor performance than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually changing the height on each animation step, you should try to use the more systematic animation, like `ValueAnimator`, or `ObjectAnimator`:

```
slidingPane.animate().scaleY(0f).setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
```

You can use `pivotY`/`pivotY` on the view to control the anchor point of the scale animation.

Related docs:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Comment: This will scale the layout, will not change the height, It is resulting in stretching the visible part of slider

Comment: how you want it to animate instead of stretching? showing more / less items in the contained list, without changing their size?

Comment: It should work same like NavigationDrawer works, just from bottom to up

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, NavigationDrawer animation doesn't change its height, but it slides it (translationY), if that's ok, try: slidingPane.animate().translateY(0f)