# How do I make a card expand animation inside a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I want to achieve an effect like [this one](https://gfycat.com/EmotionalHandyGreatwhiteshark) which I saw in the Flamingo twitter client. I have tried animating the card with something like `cardView.animate().scaleY()` but when the card changes sizes it draws on top of the others instead of moving the cards below down to fit the expanded card.

How do I achieve this effect? I am interested in the way the framework handles animations in lists and such as well so I don't want third-party library solutions.

I'll add just to make sure that my question is about how to expand items inside the recyclerView in a smooth way and not about CardViews itself.

Comment: See here how to implement this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation

Comment: See the source code for the Google Dialer app. It's call log section is a very good example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Rohan but is the Google Dialer open source?  Isn't it different from the platform dialer?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/master/src/com/android