# Android expandable recycler view with grid layout manager, with specific expanding behaviour

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I want to use an expandable recyclerview with grid layout manager, but with specific expanding behaviour which expand to the full width of the screen.

[image]

Is there any way or maybe libraries to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a transformation in your ViewHolder. Check this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation)

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if Christopher's link allows for the expandable to occupy the whole 2 grids. There might be a way using a combination of getItemViewType(), and setSpanSizeLookup().

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == positionOfClickedItem + 2){
        return TYPE_EXPANDABLE;
    } else {
        return TYPE_CAR_ITEM;
    }
}
```

Bind the data according to its position, and carry the position to your activity to set SpanSizeLookup. You would then have to notify the adapter of a change:

```
 // Create a SpanSizeLookup which returns 2 grids span if its the expandable or 1 otherwise.
    gridLayout.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            if (position == positionOfClickedItem) {
                return 2;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    });
```

I think the transformation answer works better but just in case the Span size is important.