# push and resize an animation

Tags: android, material-design

I created a `RecyclerView` which I want to animate by clicking on the `CardView` inside it. I want to apply this animation of material design which resize the selected item and push up the item below and push down the item above :

[image]

I tried with this code but it just collapses and expands without pushing the item below :

```
     private void expandCardView()
 {
      mCardViewContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
      final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
      mCardViewContent.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

      ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, mCardViewContent.getMeasuredHeight());
      mAnimator.start();
 }


 private void collapseCardView ()
 {
      int finalHeight = mCardViewContent.getHeight();

      ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(finalHeight, 0);

      mAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
      {
           @Override
           public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator)
           {
                mCardViewContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }
      });
      mAnimator.start();
 }


 private ValueAnimator slideAnimator(int start, int end)
 {

      ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);

      animator.addUpdateListener(valueAnimator->
      {
           int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
           ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mCardViewContent.getLayoutParams();
           layoutParams.height = value;
           mCardViewContent.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
      });
      return animator;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced exactly same problem in my few projects and I have found a great solution at stackoverflow, which works like charm!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13381228/6569739

You can make an invisible RelativeLayout in each RecyclerView element, which will hold all the data You want the user to see when expaned. 
Then simply call expand(View v) on specific layout to expand it.

For now that is the best and most reliable way to make this kind of animation I've found so far!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried this piece of code but i did not get what i wanted. I still have the same problem, the invisible view is still expaneded (With animation) bu without pushing the item above, it just push the item bellow

Comment: If you know the size of te expanded Layout You can make recyclerView to scroll a little bit to top (exactly to half of the expanded layout's height). It will make an effect of pushing the card above to top. The code would look sth like this:
** recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView.getScrollY() - HALF_LAYOUT_HEIGHT); **

Comment: If you know the size of te expanded Layout You can make recyclerView to scroll a little bit to top (exactly to half of the expanded layout's height). It will make an effect of pushing the card above to top. The code would look sth like this:
`recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView.getScrollY() - HALF_LAYOUT_HEIGHT);` *

Comment: You're welcome :) For a better appearance You could override the expand and collapse method, to make it return current height of the expanded layout. Then just listen to the changes and scroll the RecyclerView with the same speed / according to them :)