# LinearLayout shows and thens it animates

Tags: android, animation, android-linearlayout

My layout is about expanding and collapsing a linear layout

the collapse which is going up is working fine

but the expand, which is going down, it shows the whole view expanded at very short  period of time like ( 1ms or 2ms ) and then the animation going down started.

it's kinda annoying cause it shows the layout and then animate the layout going down.

```
public  void expand(final View v) {
    v.measure(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    // Older versions of android (pre API 21) cancel animations for views with a height of 0.
    v.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    : (int)(targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration((int) (targetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    v.startAnimation(a);
}

public static void collapse(final View v) {
    final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            if(interpolatedTime == 1){
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int)(initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration((int)(initialHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

Comment: Try to make view `INVISIBLE` or `alpha = 0f` before it expands and change it back to visible after first animation step.

Comment: i dont get it sorry.

Comment: try to v.getLayoutParams().height = 1; v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); after you start animation     v.startAnimation(a); after this

Comment: i'm sorry? what are you saying?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34714434/4704327