# How to expand and collapse an item in RecyclerView as like in Notification

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

[image]

I want to achieve expand and collapse in RecyclerView as mentioned in gif. By taping and swiping down & up.
I have tried below,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13381228/11630822
that is fine but not what I expected.
***I have used RecyclerView for listing all Notification inside the app***. If anyone have any ideas or experience , then please share with me. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

****In most of the sites, able to find way to acheive swipe left and right, but not swipe up and down. I want to achieve swipe up and down as like swipe left and swipe right.****
****In the gif I didnt use arrow for expand and collapse, I just swiped up and down. I want to achieve the samething in recyclerview inside the app.****

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Transition` or `Animator` that changes visibility of section to be expanded/collapsed, or `ConstraintSet` with different layouts.

[image]

Easiest one is to use motionLayout with different to layouts and constraintSets to change from one layout to another on button click. You can change between layouts with

```
val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
constraintSet.clone(this, R.layout.layout_collapsed)

val transition = ChangeBounds()
transition.interpolator = AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f)
transition.setDuration(300)

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(YOUR_VIEW, transition)
constraintSet.applyTo(YOUR_VIEW)
```

Expansion/collapse animation in gif with using Transitions that changes direction of button with rotating x, and expand/collapse setting item visibility and starting `TransitionManager.beginDelayed` transition

**RotateX.kt**

```
class RotateX : Transition {

    @Keep
    constructor() : super()

    @Keep
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    override fun getTransitionProperties(): Array<String> {
        return TRANSITION_PROPERTIES
    }

    override fun captureStartValues(transitionValues: TransitionValues) {
        captureValues(transitionValues)
    }

    override fun captureEndValues(transitionValues: TransitionValues) {
        captureValues(transitionValues)
    }

    override fun createAnimator(
        sceneRoot: ViewGroup,
        startValues: TransitionValues?,
        endValues: TransitionValues?
    ): Animator? {

        if (startValues == null || endValues == null) return null

        val startRotation = startValues.values[PROP_ROTATION] as Float
        val endRotation = endValues.values[PROP_ROTATION] as Float
        if (startRotation == endRotation) return null

        val view = endValues.view
        // ensure the pivot is set
        view.pivotX = view.width / 2f
        view.pivotY = view.height / 2f
        return ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.ROTATION_X, startRotation, endRotation)
    }

    private fun captureValues(transitionValues: TransitionValues) {
        val view = transitionValues.view
        if (view == null || view.width <= 0 || view.height <= 0) return
        transitionValues.values[PROP_ROTATION] = view.rotationX
    }

    companion object {

        private const val PROP_ROTATION = "iosched:rotate:rotation"
        private val TRANSITION_PROPERTIES = arrayOf(PROP_ROTATION)
    }
}
```

create xml file that targets expand button

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <transitionSet
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in">
    
        <transition class="com.smarttoolfactory.tutorial3_1transitions.transition.RotateX">
            <targets>
                <target android:targetId="@id/ivExpand" />
            </targets>
        </transition>
    
        <autoTransition android:duration="200" />
    
    </transitionSet>

My layout to be expanded or collapsed


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="2dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:transitionName="@string/transition_card_view"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivAvatar"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:src="@drawable/avatar_1_raster" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivExpand"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_expand_more_24" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:text="Some Title"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivAvatar"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:textColor="?android:textColorSecondary"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvTitle"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle"
                tools:text="Tuesday 7pm" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvBody"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="@string/bacon_ipsum_short"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivAvatar"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvDate" />


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvBody"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_image_destination" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</layout>
```

Change visibility of items to collapse or expand with

```
private fun setUpExpandedStatus() {
    if (isExpanded) {
        binding.recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.ivExpand.rotationX = 180f
    } else {
        binding.recyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.ivExpand.rotationX = 0f
    }
}
```

Start animation

```
val parent = (itemView.parent as? ViewGroup)
    
val transition = TransitionInflater.from(itemView.context)
                .inflateTransition(R.transition.icon_expand_toggle)
    
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parent, transition)
    
isExpanded = !isExpanded
    
setUpExpandedStatus()
```

I created animation and transitions samples including the one on the gif, you can check them out [there](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Animation-Tutorials).

Comment: thank you for your answer. Instead of swiping up and down using arrow, I need to do swipe by moving finger up and down. Is that possible.

Comment: In the image you posted there is a scale animation(elastic movement) after touch and then expand animation. If you wish to change height of your view with moving your finger up on down on a view you should check out ItemTouchHelper and increase decrease height based on previous position. It involves some calculations